# Ubuntu 16.04, dahdi 'make install' leads to ssl error

Tags: 16.04, drivers, software-installation, kernel, ssl

```
 INSTALL /usr/src/dahdi-linux-complete-2.11.1+2.11.1/linux/drivers/dahdi/dahdi.ko
At main.c:222:
- SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
- SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial
```

Please let me know a fix

Answer (score 2):

The problem is caused by the new and stricter method of kernel module signing.

There are [a request open in Github](https://github.com/slavrn/gm12u320/issues/14):

> braykov commented on 28 Oct 2016
>
> ```
> $ sudo make modules_install 
> make -C /lib/modules/`uname -r`/build M=`pwd` modules_install
> make[1]: Entering directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-46-generic'
>   INSTALL /home/bob/gm12u320/gm12u320.ko
> At main.c:222:
> - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
> - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
> sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
>   DEPMOD  4.4.0-46-generic
> ```

This is actually open without solution yet.

Comment: Any update on this issue?

Answer (score 0):

```
dkms install pkg/ver
```

helps from for me (/usr/src/dahdi/2.11.1)
was no "SSL error:" more

> 1. sudo dkms build dahdi/2.11.1
> 2. sudo dkms install dahdi/2.11.1