# Intel wifi Support for AX200 (Cyclone Peak)

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04, iwlwifi

**PC:** Razer Blade 15" advanced model (mid.2019)

**Wifi card:** Intel Wifi AX200 
OS: Ubuntu 18.04.2

**Issue:**
I'm unable to get the wifi working, even tho bluetooth works fine

---

**Kernel has already been updated** + apt update && apt upgrade

```bsh
razer@razer-Blade:~$ uname -sr
Linux 5.1.7-050107-generic
```

**Wifi still remains undetected**

```bsh
razer@razer-Blade:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: Native support with kernel 5.1 only.

Comment: Did you get any resolution on this?

Comment: Needed kernel 5.1+recording to Intel spec. Answered here. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WiFi Adapter AX201 Not Found: Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196308/wifi-adapter-ax201-not-found-ubuntu-18-04)

Answer (score 13):

The package `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` from the PPA [canonical-hwe-team/pc-oem-dkms](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-hwe-team/+archive/ubuntu/pc-oem-dkms) works for both kernel versions 4.15 and 5.0, the current HWE kernel. However, you need to install the package while running kernel 4.15. With kernel 5.0, you get an error during the package installation.

After the package has been successfully installed, just reboot your system, and your wifi should be working.

Comment: Thanks its work on elementaryos install at Razer Studio 2019

Comment: This worked with my Ubunto 18.04 + ASUS PCE AX3000 card w/ Intel AX200 chipset. Thank you.

Comment: `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` seems to be buggy for my Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 on Ubuntu 20.04. It works but it introduces considerable lags. For example, whenever I open a webpage I have to wait for about 2 seconds until it starts loading.

Answer (score 8):

Because you have already updated your kernel, here is another option for you.

You can try the `linux-oem-osp1` kernel and update `linux-firmware` to the latest version. This kernel is for certified OEM machines, based on 19.04's 5.0 kernel, AX200 support has been backported. I recommend this method because the packages are officially supported.

```
$ sudo apt install linux-oem-osp1 linux-firmware
```

Alternatively, for those who want to stick with the default 4.15 kernel in 18.04, you can use simply install `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` from Ubuntu archive:

```
$ sudo apt install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

The `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` package used to be in the [canonical-hwe-team/pc-oem-dkms PPA](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-hwe-team/+archive/ubuntu/pc-oem-dkms), but now it's available in the standard Ubuntu archive, saving you the trouble of adding a PPA.

Comment: This totally did the trick for my HP Pavillion 15 - cs3073cl.  Nothing else did.  Backports did not work.  Also before running the above step I enabled NVIDIA drivers: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/ubuntu-linux-install-nvidia-driver-latest-proprietary-driver/
Turned off nomodeset in the grub startup and installed intel-microcode (not sure if that helped or hurt)

Answer (score 5):

Please refers to this post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/518571/locating-drivers-for-intel-ax200-wireless-on-5-1-kernel

The author received a response from Intel. The driver itself has not made it into the kernel, therefore they suggested using their backport driver (which has now made wi-fi accessible on my laptop [mid-2019 Razer Blade])

https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release

Comment: Could you please guide me on how to install the backport driver?  I saw there is an instruction under "How to install the driver" section in this [page](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release). But, is that for a specific Intel Wifi 6 AX200 device?

Answer (score 2):

Just upgrade to the latest Linux Kernel, >5.1, and use the latest firmware for the Wireless adapter:
https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html

If you don't mind installing a new operating system, start with Ubuntu 19.10 daily build which has the latest Linux Kernel and firmware. It works out of the box:
http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/daily-live/current/

Comment: still having the same issue after upgrading to the lastest daily 19.10 build for today (17 aug. 19) and trying to copy .ucode file into the firmware folder

Comment: @lolo I had a similar problem with two of my new laptops and they both got resolved after just upgrading the Kernel to 5.2. Make sure the Kernel is actually > 5.1:
`uname -a`

Comment: This worked for me. I downloaded and install the 5.1.1 kernel: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v5.1.1/ and then I downloaded and installed the wireless adapter firmware into `/lib/firmware/` : https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/_media/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/iwlwifi-cc-46.3cfab8da.0.tgz

Answer (score 2):

-Did you install dual-boot Windows 10 and Ubuntu on your system?
If so, **please disable the 'Fast Startup' option on Windows 10.**

Details can be found at https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi, please refer to "About dual-boot with Windows and "fast-boot" enabled"

Linux* Support for Intel® Wireless Adapters

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

Comment: Thank you!! I am on a recent Linux (5.15) and had the same symptom: Intel AX200 and bluetooth showing up but not wifi. Turns out it was because fast startup was enabled in Windows.

Answer (score 1):

Here are the [Canadian Instructions](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html):

[image: Intel AX200 instructions.png]

You can install any kernel you want in Ubuntu:

- [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165)

without having to upgrade your desktop (eg 16.04 -> 18.04 -> 19.04) in order to get a new kernel version. Upgrading your desktop can result in operations loss (won't boot), in a steep learning curve and loss of functionality (but usually offset by gains in new functionality). Backups are strongly recommended when upgrading desktop. So you should plan carefully if all you want is a new kernel. Upgrading just a kernel (and keeping desktop) doesn't require a backup because the old kernel is still there to boot from.

Answer (score 0):

For my case, kernel 4.15.0-62 (ubuntu 16.04), with the use of backport driver as state by Anthony Wong,installing the driver from  https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html. The wifi work for me (not at 1Mbps).

Comment: Did you encounter the `SSL error: ...` similar to that in this [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/879275/ubuntu-16-04-dahdi-make-install-leads-to-ssl-error)? I tried following the guide [here](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release) but couldn't `sudo make install` successfully.

Comment: erm, i never encounter this error, i follw the instructions in the readme in the archive downloaded from the above link