# Unable to get wifi adapter working - clean 19.04 install - network unclaimed

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless

My wifi card is an `Intel® Wireless-AX200 (802.11/a/b/g/n/ac/ax), Bluetooth® 5`, and bluetooth is working. I've tried following various guides, however these drivers are apparently yet to make it into the kernel.

Their product brief states linux is supported:

https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/wireless/wi-fi-6-ax200-module-brief.html

And yet their driver page has no listing for them:

https://downloadcenter.intel.com/product/189347

```
sudo lshw -c network
=>
mark@m-blade-2019:~$ sudo lshw -c network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:cf300000-cf303fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 2
       logical name: enx0050b6b47e72
       serial: 00:50:b6:b4:7e:72
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=cdc_ncm driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=CDC NCM ip=192.168.1.17 link=yes multicast=yes
```

I'm running kernel version `Linux 5.0.0-13-generic`, any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT: results of `lspci -nnk | grep 00280 -A3`:

```
mark@m-blade-2019:~$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084]
    Kernel modules: wl, iwlwifi
03:00.0 Non-Volatile memory controller [0108]: Samsung Electronics Co Ltd NVMe SSD Controller SM981/PM981 [144d:a808]
mark@m-blade-2019:~$
```

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal command: `lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3` Thanks.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

According to these articles, support for this card is in kernel 5.1.*.

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-WiFi-6-AX200-Cyclone-Peak

"The product page does list Linux support that comes as little surprise these days. In fact, back in January we wrote about Linux support for these new Intel adapters within the "IWLWIFI" driver and that enablement is now present in the Linux 5.1 kernel."

https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=Intel-IWLWIFI-22260-WiFI-Linux

"The Intel WiFi Linux driver "IWLWIFI" will see support for various new WiFi adapters with the upcoming Linux 5.1 kernel cycle."

These kernels can be downloaded from https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/, or by using `ukuu` $12, from https://teejeetech.in/ukuu/

Comment: Forcing an upgrade to 5.1.0 (the only one not to crash on boot for me out of 4 or 5), wifi and bluetooth both work out the box. Thanks!

Answer (score 39):

A newer version of *iwlwifi* can be installed that includes your device and, crucially, the exact subsystem. With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethering or whatever means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi/
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

I am not certain that the firmware is included in the latest version of *linux-firmware*. If your device doesn't start working immediately, check the log for messages and we'll then address the firmware if it's missing.

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: If it does not work immediately, usually it is due to Secure Boot. Then the user has to choose between signing the installed firmware or turning off Secure Boot

Comment: Worked like a charm on my new Dell Precision 5540 with the Intel AX200 wireless component. If I could reach through the Internet, I'd buy you all a well deserved beer. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me as well on Mint 19.2 Tina with kernel 5.0.0.25-generic. Thanks!

Comment: Worked for me on my thinkpad x1 extreme gen2, on pop!_os lts version. Thanks

Comment: Worked on Dell Inspiron 5490 with Intel Dual Band Wireless 9462. Thanks a lot.

Comment: The solution did not work for me on Dell Inspiron 5491 2-in-1 with Intel wifi card 9560 
[    2.318500] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
...
[    2.318680] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: no suitable firmware found!
[    2.318682] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: minimum version required: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-39
[    2.318684] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-52
[    2.318685] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git

Comment: @ClementH. Please start your own new question.

Comment: This is the solution for intel network controllers on new x570/ubuntu builds. Thanks!

Comment: Chalk up another success via this answer, verified on a new Thinkpad X1 Extreme Gen 2 manufactured October of 2019, Ubuntu 18.04 wireless card not recognized upon install and doing all updates.  Followed answer as stated here, except rebooted after "sudo make install" as the command prompt indicated.  Did "cd backport-iwlwifi/" again after reboot, then the "sudo modprobe iwlwifi" and now wireless works.  I should mention I did set Display to "Discrete Graphics" and Secure Boot to "Disabled" in the BIOS before install.

Comment: Worked on ThinkPad P53 (Linux Mint 19.3), Thanks.

Comment: It works like a charm. Actually, saved my day

Comment: This answer and the other from George Sibble helped me at different times. My wifi would break after system update or when I'd connect to a new network and I'd have to rebuild everything. One day both answers stopped working and even after getting Xubuntu to find networks, it would freeze the entire system if I connected. I found out that my Dell XPS uses Killer Wireless AX1650 which is incompatible with Ubuntu 16.04+. Everything in [this article](https://support.killernetworking.com/knowledge-base/killer-ax1650-in-debian-ubuntu-16-04/) from the manufacturer fixed the issue permanently!

Comment: Worked for me on Linux Mint 19 Tara, kernel 4.15.0-72-generic. Didn't even have to reboot. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Didn't work in my case. I got `SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175` error message during `sudo make install`. (Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS, kernel `4.5.0-88-generic`.) @chili555, Do you happen to know what might be the possible reason for this error?

Comment: @chili555, Well, actually, after doing the above steps, the Wifi gets detected. But when I try connecting to the secured Wifi, my Ubuntu 16.04.6 completely freezes.

Comment: @IgNite I suggest that you start your own new question.

Comment: @chili555 , I started a new question [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217719/intel-wifi-6-ax200-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04). Could you please take a look?

Comment: It works for me  on Ubuntu 19  (I tried lots of options but your post helped me)

Answer (score 2):

stolen from here : https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/518577/228658 since can't mark as duplicate of a unix stack exchange page :

> According to the [product
>   page](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/products/docs/wireless/wi-fi-6-ax200-module-brief.html)
>   it's a pre-certified solution and the [driver has not been published
>   yet](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html?productId=189347&localeCode=us_en).
>
> Even Linus's Development branch doesn't [reveal
>   anything](https://livegrep.com/search/linux?q=AX200&fold_case=auto&regex=false&context=true)
>   so I'm assuming that at the time of this writing, it's not Linux
>   compatible *yet* and the article you're referring to uses marketing
>   speak for: *We'll be adding that soon...*

Comment: Linus's dev branch now shows two entries for AX200 in what appears to be v 5.4.

Answer (score 2):

For those who run into this and find that upgrading the kernel alone does not fix it. I had to also install the latest firmware as listed here: https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html. The one corresponding to Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz.

Comment: That was it! Thank you. Without this suggestion, I was getting nowhere. :)

Answer (score 2):

If you are willing to switch your kernel from the generic one to the [*OEM kernel*](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/OEMKernel), you can try the `linux-oem-osp1` package. This kernel is for certified OEM machines and is based on 19.04's 5.0 kernel, AX200 support has been backported to it.

Apart from kernel driver update, you also need to update the `linux-firmware` package to the latest version, so you should run:

```
$ sudo apt install linux-oem-osp1 linux-firmware
```

Comment: Upgrading to Ubuntu 20.04 also worked for me. Reading about the [OEM kernel](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/OEMKernel) that you linked to I saw that "the delta in OEM kernel should all be merged to the generic kernel in the next Ubuntu release". (Might have added as separate answer if I had enough reputation.)

Comment: @ArneHugo you're right, now it's time to try 20.04 as it has  already been released. When I gave my answer 20.04 didn't exist.

Answer (score 2):

Here's the solution that worked for me after the above solutions failed on a new Dell 9th gen XPS. This does involve a little custom patch so please review the code to feel comfortable with it. On a fresh install you also need git.

```
sudo apt install build-essential dkms git
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sibblegp/AX200-Patch/master/dkms.patch
patch -p1 < dkms.patch
rm dkms.patch
cd ..
sudo mv backport-iwlwifi /usr/src
sudo su
cd /usr/src
mv backport-iwlwifi/ backport-iwlwifi-git
dkms add backport-iwlwifi/git
dkms build backport-iwlwifi/git
dkms install backport-iwlwifi/git
modprobe iwlwifi
exit
```

And it should be up and running! I ran this on bare Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS.

Comment: Just a note @george-sibble, the patch is failing on `module.h` on the latest 5.0 kernel. Looks like the `cold` attribute was added to both functions. It works if  you just plop those attributes into the patch so the hunks succeed.

Comment: @stuckj Could you share what steps we have to follow for adding the attributes into the patch?

Comment: @Nivii1406, you follow his instructions above except that after the `wget` call, edit the downloaded `dkms.patch` file. There are 4 lines you need to modify (line numbers 43-44 and 52-53). Those lines have the removal of a function definition and an add of a modified version of that function definition. You'll find text that looks like `alias(...`. Put this text in front of each of the `alias(...` parts: `cold,`. That's `cold` followed by a comma. I'm not sure if you're a developer so I tried to make the instructions very clear above. :)

Comment: Here's a link to the file with my modifications. https://raw.githubusercontent.com/stuckj/AX200-Patch/master/dkms.patch. I made a PR to @George-Sibble's repo as well.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! I was not sure about what I was doing, so this definitely helps! :)