# Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS “No Wi-Fi Adapter Found”

Tags: wireless

I recently installed Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS on my Lenovo ThinkPad P1. It can now dual boot in Windows or Ubuntu. I have no idea how to get WiFi, it works fine with Windows.

`lspci` results:

```
52:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
```

`lshw -C network` results:

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:ceb00000-ceb03fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 1f.6
       bus info: pci@0000:00:1f.6
       logical name: enp0s31f6
       version: 10
       serial: 48:2a:e3:56:2c:86
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.5-4 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
       resources: irq:149 memory:cf800000-cf81ffff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

In Software & Updates, it says under “Additional Drivers”: “No additional drivers available.”

Even when under “Ubuntu Software”, under “Installable from CD-ROM/DVD”, Cdrom with Ubuntu 18.04 ‘Bionic Beaver’ is ticked (usb with installation is plugged in)

I connected my phone to my laptop and got internet using tethering

As requested I got some more information:

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 07 Oct 2019 11:36 CEST +0200

Booted last: 07 Oct 2019 00:00 CEST +0200

Script from: 22 Oct 2018 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS
Release:    18.04
Codename:   bionic

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.0.0-23-generic #24~18.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Mon Jul 29 16:12:28 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=1

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

00:1f.6 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [8086:15bc] (rev 10)
    Subsystem: Lenovo Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V [17aa:229f]
    Kernel driver in use: e1000e

52:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0080]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cb:00bd Synaptics, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 174f:2435 Syntek 
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 05ac:12a8 Apple, Inc. iPhone5/5C/5S/6
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

wmi_bmof               16384  0
intel_wmi_thunderbolt    20480  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
wmi                    28672  4 intel_wmi_thunderbolt,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

[/etc/network/interfaces]
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp0s31f6: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s31f6' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
3: enp0s20f0u1c4i2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp0s20f0u1c4i2' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 172.20.10.2/28 brd 172.20.10.15 scope global dynamic noprefixroute enp0s20f0u1c4i2
       valid_lft 85188sec preferred_lft 85188sec
    inet6 fe80::c2f:b00e:c752:a56/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.

enp0s20f0u1c4i2  no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 172.20.10.1 dev enp0s20f0u1c4i2 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev enp0s20f0u1c4i2 scope link metric 1000 
172.20.10.0/28 dev enp0s20f0u1c4i2 proto kernel scope link src 172.20.10.2 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root       903     1  0 11:30 ?        00:00:00 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s20f0u1c4i2
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Apple Inc.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        iPhone
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         ipheth
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 --
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s20f0u1c4i2' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-1/1-1:4.2/net/enp0s20f0u1c4i2
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       enp0s20f0u1c4i2
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       d89e8260-49c1-3863-8c67-afcccd0cbba3
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/1
GENERAL.METERED:                        no (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         172.20.10.2/28
IP4.GATEWAY:                            172.20.10.1
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 172.20.10.1, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 172.20.10.0/28, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        server_name = Maartens-iPhone-XR
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        expiry = 1570526174
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       next_server = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_netbios_scope = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       dhcp_message_type = 5
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       dhcp_lease_time = 85536
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       ip_address = 172.20.10.2
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       routers = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.240
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       broadcast_address = 172.20.10.15
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       domain_name_servers = 172.20.10.1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_netbios_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[26]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[27]:                       network_number = 172.20.10.0
DHCP4.OPTION[28]:                       dhcp_server_identifier = 172.20.10.1
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::c2f:b00e:c752:a56/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 256
IP6.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/{2}
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   d89e8260-49c1-3863-8c67-afcccd0cbba3 | Wired connection 2

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp0s31f6
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Intel Corporation
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        Ethernet Connection (7) I219-V
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         e1000e
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 3.2.6-k
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               0.5-4
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp0s31f6' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1f.6/net/enp0s31f6
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

[main]
NetworkingEnabled=true
WirelessEnabled=true
WWANEnabled=true

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:wwan

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no
wifi.cloned-mac-address=preserve
ethernet.cloned-mac-address=preserve

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

nl80211 not found.

##### iwlist channels ###################

enp0s31f6  no frequency information.

enp0s20f0u1c4i2  no frequency information.

lo        no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

enp0s31f6  Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp0s20f0u1c4i2  Interface doesn't support scanning.

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

##### module parameters #################

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist i2c_i801
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[    4.670373] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
[   40.070239] ipheth 1-1:4.2 enp0s20f0u1c4i2: renamed from eth0
[   41.321642] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): enp0s20f0u1c4i2: link becomes ready

########## wireless info END ############
```

Comment: Are you able to connect through ethernet, even for a short time. I mean, do you have access to the internet at all?

Comment: I have not tried ethernet yet, I can try it in 10 hours maybe

Comment: Actually I don’t think I have the right cable, so a solution without ethernet connection would be better

Comment: When you get internet access, you can run this Wireless Info Script: https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info as described in this AskUbuntu post: https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos/425205#425205 It'll create wireless-info.txt file at the location it is run from; then edit your original post, and copy paste the output from that TXT file. Info about the script, as mentioned in the post, "we created at the Ubuntu Forums to collect all the most common information needed while masking all sensitive data."

Comment: Just read your 2nd comment. Since you mentioned WiFi works fine with Windows, if you feel comfortable, you could download the script in Windows, then reboot to Ubuntu, run the script, again switch the OSes, and update this post from Windows. Here's the download link from the same page: https://github.com/UbuntuForums/wireless-info/raw/master/wireless-info Go through "Run from GUI" at the bottom of GitHub page. To make it "executable" using GUI, once in Ubuntu, right-click on the file, properties, click permissions tab, and select "Allow executing file as a program".

Comment: Another option would be, again if you feel comfortable, you can go to device manager in Windows, look for wireless adapter, and find make/model number of your WiFi card/adapter. Update your post with the info. That will help finding and installing correct drivers.

Comment: I got a connection by using tethernet with my phone, more information is now in the original post

Comment: It seems that you redacted some information from `lshw -C network`. Please if you are pasting some outputs, paste it as it is produced. For your issue, see if [chili555's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1156246/816190) helps.

Comment: @maarten-meijer it looks like wireless card in your laptop is: Intel Wireless-AX200. Please check the answer mentioned by"Kulfy". Also go through another answer by [chili555](https://askubuntu.com/a/1156246/928088).

Comment: All code in chili555's answer worked, except for the last instruction 'sudo modprobe iwlwifi'. It results: 'sudo modprobe iwlwifi'

Comment: I reinstalled Ubuntu with proprietary software checked. I now have secure boot. I updated the information

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Unable to get wifi adapter working - clean 19.04 install - network unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed)

Answer (score 0):

Apparently Secure Boot was enabled, which is also why [chili555's answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1156246/928088) did not work. I entered the bios and manually turned Secure Boot off. After this everything was fixed!