# 18.04.1: Lenovo P1 Gen 2 No Wifi adapter found

Tags: 18.04, wireless, intel, adapter

I want to install Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS on my [Lenovo P1 gen 2](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-p/P1-Gen-2/p/20QTS00C00) alongside windows 10.  I've done this many times before with previous computers, distros, etc. but this computer is new (and different in that it has no ethernet port, and I'm having trouble with the Wifi).

Looking at the similar problems previously asked, here are the outputs to some commands (sorry that I am copying them by hand, I can not connect to the internet on my Lenovo):

> rfkill list all
>
> > 0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
> >     Soft black: no
> >     Hard block: no

To me, it seems like it isn't even identifying that the computer has Wifi capabilities? Anyway, the relevant controllers:

```
> lspci
>> 00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Ethernet Connection (7) I219-LM (rev 10)
>> 52:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
>> 53:00.0 SD Host controller: Genesys Logic, Inc Device 9755
```

And hopefully everything else that is needed:

```
> sudo lshw -C network
>> *-network UNCLAIMED
>>> description: Network controller
>>> product: Intel Corporation
>>> vendor: Intel Corporation
>>> physical id: 0
>>> bus info: pci@0000:52:00.0
>>> version: 1a
>>> width: 64 bits
>>> clock: 33MHz
>>> capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
>>> configuration: latency=0
>>> resources: memory:d8c00000-d8c03fff

>> Then there is more on the *-network Ethernet interface and the fd auto negotiation
```

and

```
>lsusb
>> Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>> Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>> Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
>> Bus 001 Device 003: ID 06cd:00bd Synaptics, Inc.
>> Bus 001 Device 002: ID 04f2:b67c Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd
>> Bus 001 Device 004: ID 8087:0029 Intel Corp.
>> Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Other notes:

The wifi works perfectly well on the windows side of the computer.  I've tried to install Mint, and the same exact problem - that the Wifi adapter can not be found, arises.

A big source of difficulty for me at this point is that I am new to computers without ethernet ports, and so if I can not establish a wired connection to download 3rd-party software, how is one to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance, this community is a lifesaver!

Comment: Take a look at https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WifiDocs/WirelessTroubleShootingGuide  Looking through the output of dmesg for firmware load failures, and anything related to your wlan usually helps identify a problem.

Comment: Does this help you? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed

Comment: This problem is only occurring with 18.04.1.  I tried 19.10 this morning and had no problems.

Answer (score 0):

The specs linked above in the first line of your question show it has a Mini Gigabit Ethernet port, #4 in this picture.  [image: Left side ports]

Attach a Gigabit Ethernet dongle to that port for the connectivity you need for the installation.

Comment: Thanks I appreciate the help, I truly had no idea what a mini gigbit ethernet port was before this.  After ordering the appropriate adapters and installing Ubuntu with a wired internet connection, it sadly did not fix my issue.  Thanks for the input though, transitioning to this decade's technology has been a blast :')