# No Wi-Fi Adaptor Found - Ubuntu - iwlwifi

Tags: networking, drivers, 18.04

I installed ubuntu 18.04 on HP envy. However I am getting issue setting up wifi :-

**No Wi-Fi adapter found**

The output of following command is :-

lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280

**Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi**

I tried steps mentioned in
http://ubuntuhandbook.org/index.php/2019/04/nstall-rtl8723de-wifi-driver-ubuntu-19-04/
with no success.

Could anyone please help me with the issue.

Comment: I think this answer might help you restore WiFi if you have ethernet to install drivers as detailed in it: `https://askubuntu.com/a/1156246/928088`

Comment: Also go through this answer from the same thread: `https://askubuntu.com/a/1156187/928088`

Comment: Thanks man first one worked. Please convert this to an answer to help other users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Unable to get wifi adapter working - clean 19.04 install - network unclaimed](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @karel Yes that worked

Comment: @ravi As you mentioned, I've just posted the answer, and I'm glad that it worked out for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can install the newer `iwlwifi` drivers as detailed in this [AskUbuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed/1156246#1156246):

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi/
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Your WiFi adapter should be working now.