# WiFi adapter not found Ubuntu 19.10

Tags: networking, drivers

I've come a long way googling and trying to fix this problem on my Zenbook and still not solve it.. 
It all started when Wi-Fi suddenly disappeared on Windows 10, however the adapter continued to appear in the device manager as working. I've rolled back to the save point - but it didn’t help, reinstall Windows -- still no Wi-Fi.

Then I removed Windows and installed Ubuntu 19.10. There was no network during installation and after booting I see Wi-Fi adapter not found.
But:

```
skazzi@skazzi-ZenBook-UX450FD-UX450FD:~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; 
00:14.3 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:9df0] (rev 30)
    DeviceName: WLAN
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC] [8086:0000]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi

skazzi@skazzi-ZenBook-UX450FD-UX450FD:~$ iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.

skazzi@skazzi-ZenBook-UX450FD-UX450FD:~$ rfkill list
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: asus-wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: asus-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

I've done all regular stuff as updating drivers, disabling fast and secure boot. What are these error messages about?

```
skazzi@skazzi-ZenBook-UX450FD-UX450FD:~$ dmesg | grep -i firm
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST: CPU0: -14780265 force to 0
[    0.144642] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.004457] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs within socket(s), fixing all errors
[    2.665673] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.691061] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 0 week 0 2000
[    2.691837] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-17-0-0.sfi failed with error -2
[    2.691839] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    2.711513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    2.961250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    2.964354] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
skazzi@skazzi-ZenBook-UX450FD-UX450FD:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
[    2.652802] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    2.665366] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.665368] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    2.665673] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    2.704604] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9460, REV=0x318
[    2.711102] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    2.711513] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    2.715847] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    2.715854] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    2.715869] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    2.715879] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xBC77D003 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    2.715889] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5FCD92EA | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    2.715899] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x67FF4ED6 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    2.715909] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x9B77AC53 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    2.715919] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x50818C44 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    2.715929] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x90154002 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    2.715939] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xF1DDEF34 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    2.715949] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xCF2F43FA | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    2.715959] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    2.716002] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    2.716077] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    2.716152] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    2.716317] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2, CPU2 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2
[    2.716320] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    2.716323] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[    2.961250] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    2.973095] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

Can it be a hardware problem while system detects adapter? Did not notice anything strange inside laptop. Also tried to disconnect and turn on the battery again -- did not help. 
I don’t know what else can be done and hope for help.

Upd. Suddenly noticed,that there are also no Bluetooth adapters found. Are they somehow related with Wi-Fi?

Answer (score 1):

If you could not use wi-fi adapter in both Windows (even if reinstalled) and Linux, then it's more probably a hardware related issue. If you could disconnect your Wi-Fi adapter by hand then you could replace it. Just buy almost the same Wi-Fi adapter and [replace it](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VyUOwtjP864).

System could detect wrongly working hardware, but could not use it as in your case. Having a bunch of features in different circuits with different elements hardware could partially work. Elements could be enabled in parallel also, so a hardware module could still work, but not as it is required. It could be detected, but could not do what drivers say it to do.

Comment: Sounds reasonable, I was about to buy external adapter, but now I like your option more. Thank you for link

Answer (score 1):

If you have working internet by other means (wired or through USB tethering), you could try installing the newer `iwlwifi` drivers:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install git build-essential
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi/
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make -j4
sudo make install
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Reference: [AskUbuntu thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed/1156246#1156246).

Answer (score 0):

In my Asus Zenbook UX5401 with ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS after today update to kernel 5.15.0.50-generic almost work perfect.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).