# Intel Wireless AC-9560 doesn't work in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: 20.04, iwlwifi

My Intel wireless card has not worked on my laptop for some time. My laptop is dual booted and for a long time I thought it was Windows 10, but after seeing some old questions I think it may be Ubuntu causing the issue.

I just recently updated to Focal (Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS), because of the issues of Bionic with the wireless card. See previous questions [Unable to load iwlwifi for Intel Wireless-AC 9560 card](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux-firmware/+bug/1864509) and [Broken wifi on ASUS laptop 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1224137/broken-wifi-on-asus-laptop-18-04).

Anyway, updating to Ubuntu 20.01.1 LTS has not solved the issue. My wireless card is still broken not working. It shows no wireless networks when I open Ubuntu settings, but it appears to know the card is there. Windows can also detect the card but says there is a driver issue.

I am not sure what info one might need to debug this problem but here is some basic info:

```
user@zenbook:~$ uname -r
5.4.0-49-generic
```

```
user@zenbook:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Cannon Point-LP CNVi [Wireless-AC]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 30
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:b431c000-b431ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@1:1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: c2:91:b1:f0:da:b7
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.116 link=yes multicast=yes
```

```
user@zenbook:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
user@zenbook:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
    3.359400] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.365215] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.365218] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.365974] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.430918] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 9460, REV=0x318
[    3.438050] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.438382] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.441760] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Microcode SW error detected. Restarting 0x0.
[    3.441767] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Not valid error log pointer 0x00000000 for Init uCode
[    3.441782] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Fseq Registers:
[    3.441793] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x8FFD2E38 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    3.441803] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xABF742AA | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    3.441812] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xDB830A51 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    3.441822] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xAAD76E9F | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    3.441832] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x3A661215 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    3.441842] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x5F92D0C4 | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    3.441852] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xE4297F25 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    3.441862] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x0F4D169D | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    3.441872] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0x01000100 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.441915] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    3.441990] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    3.442065] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: 0xA5A5A5A2 | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    3.442229] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2, CPU2 Status: 0xa5a5a5a2
[    3.442232] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to start INIT ucode: -5
[    3.442234] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Collecting data: trigger 16 fired.
[    3.689141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    3.700820] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Failed to run INIT ucode: -5
```

```
user@zenbook:~$ dmesg|grep -i firmware
[    0.000000] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST: CPU0: -222193062 force to 0
[    0.135927] Spectre V2 : Enabling Restricted Speculation for firmware calls
[    0.004439] [Firmware Bug]: TSC ADJUST differs within socket(s), fixing all errors
[    3.365974] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: loaded firmware version 46.6bf1df06.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.416775] Bluetooth: hci0: Minimum firmware build 0 week 0 2000
[    3.417402] bluetooth hci0: Direct firmware load for intel/ibt-17-0-0.sfi failed with error -2
[    3.417404] Bluetooth: hci0: Failed to load Intel firmware file (-2)
[    3.438382] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    3.689141] iwlwifi 0000:00:14.3: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    3.737985] [drm] Finished loading DMC firmware i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_04.bin (v1.4)
```

Any help would be great, if anybody managed to fix this issue?

Comment: Is this a possible issue? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled

Comment: Hi, thanks for responding, I have fast-boot turned off in Windows.

Comment: For posterity, I tried the recommended solution here [https://askubuntu.com/a/1212600/1133827](https://askubuntu.com/a/1212600/1133827), which did not fix the problem. It is strange that both the wireless function and the bluetooth do not work. I am starting to think this is a hardware failure and need to replace the wireless card.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact output from iwlwifi (Also an AC-9560 adapter on Ubuntu 20.04) and Ubuntu could not identify a wifi adapter.

The fix I stumbled upon was enabling Secure Boot in my BIOS which kind of makes sense in retrospect.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for the response! I tried this, turned SecureBoot on, but it did not fix my issue. I have not looked at this in a while, I have just been using a wired connection. I am convinced it is some incompatibility between ubuntu 20.04, the intel wireless card, and iwlwifi. That or it is an actual hardware issue.