# Wifi adapter not found Ubuntu 18.04 tried rtlwifi-new, rtl8723de and bcmwl-kernel-source

Tags: networking, 18.04, drivers

I have searched all the answers to this issue but none have worked for me so far.

when I run: `lspci -v | grep Network`
i get this output:

```
03:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2723 (rev 1a)
Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device 1654
```

and when I run:

```
lshw -C network
```

my output is:

```
    *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: enp2s0
       version: 21
       serial: b4:2e:99:a4:58:c9
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168h-2_0.0.2 02/26/15 ip=192.168.1.63 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:18 ioport:3000(size=256) memory:58404000-58404fff memory:58400000-58403fff

  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:58300000-58303fff
```

What I have tried:

```
sudo apt remove bcmwl-kernel-source && sudo apt install git dkms
git clone -b extended https://github.com/lwfinger/rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms add ./rtlwifi_new
sudo dkms install rtlwifi-new/0.6
```

then I rebooted the system

This didnt work so I tried this tutorial:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dokG4bCF4GQ&t=331s

Then I tried:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall bcmwl-kernel-source
```

and rebooted and still did not work.

I don't really know what else to try at this point, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the kernel version `uname -a`?

Comment: its Linux aida-AERO-15-XA 5.3.0-51-generic #44~18.04.2-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 23 14:27:18 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

You have an Intel AX200 device.

It is now supported natively by Linux kernel.

To get it working you need to install the correct kernel and update `linux-firmware`.

Connect to the internet and run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
sudo apt install linux-firmware
```

Reboot and Wi-Fi should work.

Comment: I just tried this and I still get the message of "No Wifi Adapter Found" when I go to settings > wifi.

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed