# Ubuntu - 18.04 can't install a WiFi driver on Lenovo Thinkpad E14 gen2

Tags: 18.04, wireless, lenovo, thinkpad

Not sure how to install a WiFi driver in Ubuntu 18.04 as I have tried many way to solve the issue. Now I can't connect to internet through WiFi. I couldn't find a solution for Thinkpad E14 gen 2

[image: no wifi driver]

Comment: The problem is finally resolved. Following this instruction to download a newer version of iwlwifi and make sure to disable secure boot before. https://askubuntu.com/a/1156246/1175174

Comment: What kernel are you using? Is suspend working for you?

Comment: I'm using " Linux version 4.15.0-135-generic"

Comment: Can you please take a look at this: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/635492/ubuntu-wont-boot-after-kernel-update/635531  Can you try a kernel after 5.5?

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED:
must update kernel to 5.11
You can do this by installing Ubuntu Mainline Kernel installer.
There are tutorials on line on how to install Mainline.
The lenovo thinkpad  P14s uses the AX201 wifi 6
and is therefore not supported in lower kernel.
Do remember that newer kernels may not be stable and could
lead to other issues until it is certified as stable.

Hope this helps someone else out there.

Answer (score 1):

Installing Ubuntu 21.04 (kernel 5.11) allowed me to use Intel WiFi 6 hardware.

Answer (score 0):

For E14 Gen3 I had to manually install drivers. Follow instructions from https://github.com/lwfinger/rtw89