# Intel wifi AX200 does not work on ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, wireless, kernel, iwlwifi

I have read the reference ([Intel wifi Support for AX200 (Cyclone Peak)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149116/intel-wifi-support-for-ax200-cyclone-peak)), but I still have problems about this issue.

I tried to manually update to 5.1, but somehow it creates more problems, so I reinstalled ubuntu 16.04 again. I followed the instruction from https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lKqZ1sv0DVc, but it only updates to kernel 4.15.0-65 and says it's the newest version:

```
$ sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04
(optional to add xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04)
Reboot and check your system works ok
$ sudo apt-get autoremove
$ sudo apt-get purge linux-generic linux-headers-generic linux-image-generic
```

Besides, in Linux* Support for Intel® Wireless Adapters website (https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html). Should I still download the firmware of Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, even though it says the kernel need 5.1+?

Can somebody provide code guidance? thanks very much!

Comment: It needs kernel 5.1+ Ubuntu 16.04 is too old for that. You can install a mainline 5.1 kernel with no guarantee.

Answer (score 0):

If you do decide on 5.1 kernel, I would skip to 5.3 kernel instead. Latest is version 5.3.6 released October 11, 2019:

- [How to update kernel to the latest mainline version without any Distro-upgrade?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/119080/how-to-update-kernel-to-the-latest-mainline-version-without-any-distro-upgrade/885165#885165)

Updating the kernel is less risky than updating the entire desktop and all your applications. After installing a new kernel you can still boot your previous kernel in grub. OTOH, after installing a new desktop your old desktop is gone and the only way of going back is to restore backups or reinstall.