# Intel WiFi 6 AX200 not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: drivers, kernel, iwlwifi, firmware, backport

According to [Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html), Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz device is only guaranteed to work with the kernel version **`5.1+`**. (For your information, it works on Ubuntu 18.04.4 LTS with kernel version `5.3.0-28`.)

**What I want to achieve**

However, I need to get Intel Wi-Fi 6 AX200 working on Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with kernel version **`4.15.0-88`**. (The reason is that I need CUDA 10 Toolkit, and the highest version of kernel supported by CUDA 10, as of this post, is `4.15` according to [NVIDIA](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html#system-requirements).)

Is there any way to get this work in Ubuntu 16.04.6 with kernel `4.15`?

**What I tried**

- I tried copying the firmware, by following [this](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi), but no differnce:

  ```bsh
  git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
  cd linux-firmware
  cp iwlwifi-*.ucode /lib/firmware
  ```
- I tried installing the backport driver by following this [guide](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release) but it gives the following error:

  ```bsh
  git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
  cd backport-iwlwifi
  make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
  sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
  make -j4
  sudo make install
  ...
  ...
  At main.c:160:
  - SSL error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory: bss_file.c:175
  - SSL error:2006D080:BIO routines:BIO_new_file:no such file: bss_file.c:178
  sign-file: certs/signing_key.pem: No such file or directory
  ...
  ```

  The Wifi does get detected after reboot. However, Ubuntu freezes just right after trying to connect.

  Here are some of the information.

  ```bsh
  user@laptop:~$ sudo modprobe iwlwifi
  ```

  ```bsh
  user@laptop:~$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep file
  filename:       /lib/modules/4.15.0-91-generic/updates/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
  parm:           nvm_file:NVM file name (charp)
  ```

  ```bsh
  user@laptop:~$ dmesg | grep iwl
  [    4.857473] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
  [    4.857474] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
  [    4.931567] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
  [    4.938095] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
  [    4.938218] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
  [    4.938328] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
  [    4.938555] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
  [    4.938567] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
  [    4.938577] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
  [    4.940246] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 58.3.35.22
  [    4.940249] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
  [    4.940251] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
  [    4.940498] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 50.3e391d3e.0 cc-a0-50.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
  [    4.940511] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
  [    4.958898] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
  [    5.128296] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: 50:eb:71:74:fc:52
  [    5.216966] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
  [    7.615869] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
  ```

  ```bsh
  user@laptop:~$ rfkill list all
  0: hci0: Bluetooth
      Soft blocked: yes
      Hard blocked: no
  1: phy0: Wireless LAN
      Soft blocked: nob
      Hard blocked: no
  ```

  ```bsh
  user@laptop:~$ cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e iwl -e wlp
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.089819] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.089820] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8324:9176b151
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.120067] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.127062] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.127308] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.128596] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.128618] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.129199] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.129220] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.129318] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.129334] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.131300] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.131308] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.131311] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.131728] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 cc-a0-48.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.131751] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.174508] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.186490] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.187531] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.344711] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: base HW address: 50:eb:71:74:fc:52
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.360401] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0 wlp4s0: renamed from wlan0
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629726.7886] rfkill1: found WiFi radio killswitch (at /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.5/0000:04:00.0/ieee80211/phy0/rfkill1) (driver iwlwifi)
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629726.8192] devices added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.5/0000:04:00.0/net/wlp4s0, iface: wlp4s0)
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629726.8192] device added (path: /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1d.5/0000:04:00.0/net/wlp4s0, iface: wlp4s0): no ifupdown configuration found.
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629726.8499] (wlp4s0): using nl80211 for WiFi device control
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629726.8512] device (wlp4s0): driver supports Access Point (AP) mode
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629726.8523] manager: (wlp4s0): new 802.11 WiFi device (/org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/0)
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629726.8535] device (wlp4s0): state change: unmanaged -> unavailable (reason 'managed') [10 20 2]
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.780946] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
  Mar 19 21:55:26 laptop kernel: [    4.792594] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
  Mar 19 21:55:27 laptop kernel: [    4.942557] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
  Mar 19 21:55:27 laptop kernel: [    4.948463] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: BIOS contains WGDS but no WRDS
  Mar 19 21:55:27 laptop kernel: [    4.950788] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
  Mar 19 21:55:27 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629727.1088] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: init -> starting
  Mar 19 21:55:27 laptop wpa_supplicant[1193]: Could not read interface p2p-dev-wlp4s0 flags: No such device
  Mar 19 21:55:27 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629727.1881] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: starting -> ready
  Mar 19 21:55:27 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629727.1882] device (wlp4s0): state change: unavailable -> disconnected (reason 'supplicant-available') [20 30 42]
  Mar 19 21:55:27 laptop kernel: [    5.115444] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp4s0: link is not ready
  Mar 19 21:55:30 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629730.4391] device (wlp4s0): supplicant interface state: ready -> inactive
  Mar 19 21:55:52 laptop NetworkManager[1003]: <info>  [1584629752.8460] device (wlp4s0): Activation: starting connection 'AndroidAPA24A' (fbf53422-d295-49ed-b45c-6c5383cb931c)
  Binary file (standard input) matches
  ```

**Notes**

- In a similar [post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1181518/intel-wifi-ax200-does-not-work-on-ubuntu-16-04), the provided answer is to upgrade the kernel to `5.1+`, which doesn't meet the requirement in my case.

Comment: Please see: https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback/issues/139 "afaict, the error is unrelated and not harmful: during make install the system also tries to sign the module, and since you do not have the required keys to sign, this fails. nevertheless the make install succeeds, and you should be able the module." Can you load the module? `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` Did the backports version actually install? `modinfo iwlwifi | grep file` Are there any clues in the message log? `dmesg | grep iwl` Or here? `rfkill list all`

Comment: @chili555 , Thanks for taking a look. I proceeded as you suggested but Ubuntu freezes right after trying to connect to WiFi. I edited my question, adding results as requested.

Comment: Are there any clues here? `cat /var/log/syslog | grep -e iwl -e wlp | tail -n 15` Please try: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi && sudo modprobe iwlwifi disable_11ax=y` Now try to connect. Does it still freeze?

Comment: No luck; it still freezes. (I added the result of `/var/log/syslog/` in my question. But I think the message is not relevant, because the time in the message was `07:54`, but the most recent time when I tried to connect the WiFi was ~`08:30`.)

Comment: I think I found another approach, but I have completely no idea how it is different: install `backport-iwlwifi-dkms` from this [repository](https://launchpad.net/~canonical-hwe-team/+archive/ubuntu/backport-iwlwifi).

Comment: The driver itself is no different at all. ‘dkms’ means that the driver needn’t be re-compiled and reinstalled after every kernel update.

Comment: The log suggests that iwlwifi is not the cause of the freeze.

Comment: @chili555, Sorry for not getting back for a while. I was fixing a famous Nvidia driver login loop. So, I tried again and I updated `/var/log/syslog` in my question.

Comment: Again, we nothing related to the driver iwlwifi that suggests a crash or freeze. You might also check: `grep etwork /var/log/syslog` to see if Network Manager has any clues. As the output will be lengthy, post the result here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com

Answer (score 4):

I have completely no idea how [this repository](https://launchpad.net/%7Ecanonical-hwe-team/+archive/ubuntu/backport-iwlwifi) is different from [the official backport](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi/core_release) driver from Intel. But it does work on my laptop.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
```

Comment: I was unable to add a comment due to my lack of reputation, but i got all the same exact errors as above and the official backport did not work for me either but this did.

Comment: Did it work for you? I did it, but I still get the same error: SSL...

Comment: This worked for me, Ubuntu 20.04.2, (HP Elitebook 845 G7). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Only for ubuntu 16.04 lts checked

1. Check kernel version `uname -a` if version no 4.15
   update to 4.15 `sudo apt-get install --install-recommends linux-generic-hwe-16.04 xserver-xorg-hwe-16.04`
   If update kernel need reboot
2. Just copy and paste

```
git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi
sudo make defconfig-iwlwifi-public;sudo make; sudo make install
git clone git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
cd linux-firmware/
sudo cp iwlwifi-* /lib/firmware/
reboot
```

Comment: Hi, perhaps you could be more elaborate about what the commands will do, so others can learn/understand what is done here ;)