# Intel WiFi 6 AX210 not working on Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, drivers, kernel

my wifi device is only guaranteed to work with the kernel version 5.2+.
i need to get wifi 6 AX 210 working on UBuntu 16.04, since I need ros Kinetic for my project.
I've tried all the steps in this threed :[Intel WiFi 6 AX200 not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217719/intel-wifi-6-ax200-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04)

and I had the same results, so my laptop was freezing ..etc.
Is there any possiblity I can get my wifi device to work, such as updating the kernel and how can I do that.

Comment: Did you also try @IgNite answer at the link you gave? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Yes, I have tried that as well. But now i got it to work using a newer kernet version and IgNite answer:  I've used ukuu to update my kernel to 5.9.1 but there I couldn't connect to Wifi and Eathernet as well after that I used for the new kernel the @IgNite aswer and see it worked

Comment: See my answer on : [Intel WiFi 6 AX200 not working on Ubuntu 16.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1217719/intel-wifi-6-ax200-not-working-on-ubuntu-16-04) Checked on AX210

Answer (score 0):

Intel does [not officially support](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html) AX210 wireless adapters on Linux yet, sorry. I had to find that out the hard way myself.

Linux 5.10 should bring the necessary firmware though, that should probably be available in ubuntu sometime in January.

Edit: It seems you've already managed to get it working, nice. I just wanted to add that I would recommend upgrading to a newer LTS release by April because public support is running out for this one.

Comment: That is wrong. It is supported. See https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1902848

Comment: Yeah but that is for linux 5.10. Is anybody even shipping 5.10 right now? I know Arch isn't.

Comment: This is not a question of shipping. The device is supported, the firmware and a kernel image are available.

Comment: Okay well you're arguing semantics. Intel isn't officially supporting this card yet, and ubuntu 16.04 certainly isn't either

Comment: Intel released firmware for this adapter that can be used on Linux. Linux maintalners added support to kernel. A true statement would be: "the adapter is not supported by Ubuntu releases out of the box till the 5.10 OEM kernel is moved from `proposed` to `main`". Linux kernels don't "bring firmware" anywhere.

Comment: The 5.10 OEM should appear in `main` in a week or two.

Comment: And you could have noticed the OP's comment that they got it working even on 16.04.

Comment: Yeah sorry I didn't see that. I still wonder though why somebody would be running a 4 year old lts release just to install beta quality kernels.

Comment: Just tested in arch with kernel 5.10.2 from testing, wifi "works" but Bluetooth does not (resetting adapter twice per second) and delays boot by 1.5min because of that. Pretty far from what I would call working or supported

Answer (score 0):

I still have a problem with the AX210 on my Dell laptop with every kernel release.

Here's the solution that works for me on kernel 5.11.0-36-generic with Ubuntu 20.04.

```
sudo mv /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pwm /lib/firmware/iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0.pwm.bak
```

It works just fine if the extra iwlwifi driver is not loaded.