# 20.04.3LTS not seeing new wireless card AX210

Tags: networking, 20.04

According to everything I've been able to find this SHOULD be working.  I have the 5.11.0-46-generic kernel installed (supposedly the 5.10 kernel was the first to support this card).  Output from lspci -nnk | grep 0280 -A3 is:

```
07:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0024]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

Yet when I try to activate wireless from Gnome settings, it says a wireless card has not been detected.  What am I missing here?

Comment: The driver is present on your system but didn't load, for some reason. Let's find out why. Please edit your question to show the result of: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl` Firmware??

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ubuntu 20.04 LTS driver Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326386/ubuntu-20-04-lts-driver-intel-wi-fi-6e-ax210-160mhz)

Comment: @chili555 That command didn't return any information.

Comment: Let's try harder. How about: `sudo modprobe -r iwlwifi` and: `sudo modprobe -v iwlwifi` and finally: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: This was pointed out in another forum. It's a bug in the kernel that hopefully gets fixed but here is the workaround:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-5-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update/1360291#1360291

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intel Wifi 6 AX210 - WiFi not working after Update](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360175/intel-wifi-6-ax210-wifi-not-working-after-update)