# Both Wifi and Bluetooth are not working in fresh install ubuntu 21.10

Tags: networking, drivers, bluetooth

This is my first time trying Linux

I first installed Ubuntu 20.04 and had the same problem where wifi and bluetooth icons wouldn't show in the bar menu, and wouldn't appear in settings menu.

I checked "Software & Updates" in case a driver were missing and it didn't showed, then i decided to install Ubuntu 21.10 in case that would help solve the problem and it keeps exactly the same.

I read [this post](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326386/ubuntu-20-04-lts-driver-intel-wi-fi-6e-ax210-160mhz) and thought for a moment that this could be the error, and i just needed to wait for kernel 5.10, but then i did:

```
carlos@carlos:~$ uname -r 
5.13.0-30-generic
```

And i have a higher version of that, so i don't know what could be the cause of this problem.

When i tried to check my bluetooth driver with:

```
carlos@carlos:~$ sudo dmesg | grep -i blue
[sudo] password for carlos: 
[    2.535744] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    2.535758] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    2.535760] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    2.535762] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    2.535763] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    2.548911] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
[    2.548925] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Read version failed (-22)
[    2.548983] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
[    3.381017] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
[    3.381035] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Read version failed (-22)
[    3.381223] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
[    3.407056] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    3.407063] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    3.407070] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    3.976981] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
[    3.976998] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Read version failed (-22)
[    3.977171] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
[    4.813015] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
[    4.813032] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Read version failed (-22)
[    4.813212] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
[    5.641009] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
[    5.641027] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Read version failed (-22)
[    5.641193] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
[    6.233004] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
[    6.233022] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Read version failed (-22)
[    6.233185] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
[    6.825024] Bluetooth: hci0: Reading Intel version information failed (-22)
[    6.825041] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel Read version failed (-22)
[    6.825202] Bluetooth: hci0: Intel reset sent to retry FW download
```

Then, with my wifi i did:

```
carlos@carlos:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 14.3
       bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
       version: 11
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:600-5ff memory:600111c000-600111ffff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: Ethernet Controller I225-V
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
       logical name: enp3s0
       version: 03
       serial: d8:bb:c1:a5:ca:3d
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi msix pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igc driverversion=5.13.0-30-generic duplex=full firmware=1073:8754 ip=192.168.0.105 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:18 memory:51800000-518fffff memory:51900000-51903fff
```

I think it is also important to note that i also have Windows 10 installed on my SSD, in case that could cause some problems. And both wifi and bluetooth works perfectly fine there.

My Motherboard is a MSI z690-A Pro DDR4 Wifi.

EDIT: The problem has been solved, it turned out that the firmware version was newer than the kernel implementation.

I used [mainline](https://github.com/bkw777/mainline) and select the lastest version and now i have both wifi and bluetooth working flawlessly

Comment: Is this an issue? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I've done it, still have the same problem

Comment: Please edit your question to show the result of the terminal commands: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi` and also: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Thank you very much, i've just solved my problem, i added a brief description of what turned out to be the problem and how i solved it.