# Driver Issue with Intel® Wi-Fi 6E AX210 on Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS -- reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)

Tags: networking, drivers, 22.04, intel

I run into a well-known problem that was actually already widely discussed on the web. However, I unfortunately could not solve the problem yet.

I recently replaced the Wifi network adapter into a new one, **Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz**, in a Dell Rugged 5414 laptop, several years old.

I'm still fairly new to Linux/Ubuntu and appreciate any assistance.

```
root@laptop-02# lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description: Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS
Release: 22.04
Codename: jammy
```

The network adapter was correctly recognized by the system:

```
root@laptop-02# lspci -knn | grep Net -A3
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210/AX211/AX411 160MHz [8086:2725] (rev 1a)
Subsystem: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz [8086:0024]
Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

**However, the system shows the WLAN function as switched off. Wireless networks are not displayed. The function is greyed out in Ubuntu.**

```
root@laptop-02# sudo iwconfig
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp0s31f6  no wireless extensions.
enx10050197f9a6  no wireless extensions.
wwan0     no wireless extensions.
wlp1s0    no wireless extensions.
```

The first errors are displayed here:

- reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
- Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-73.ucode failed with error -2

```
root@laptop-02:/usr/lib/firmware# dmesg | grep wifi
[    4.914540] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[    4.914541] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27
[    4.997046] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    5.003663] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-73.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.003684] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode failed with error -2
[    5.009461] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    5.009490] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
[    5.010086] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 71.058653f6.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-71.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    5.109985] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[    5.116435] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[    5.288652] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded PNVM version 05a8dfca
[    5.304238] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[    5.377673] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: 8c:f8:c5:3b:dc:c4
[    6.498280] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
[ 3575.564341] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[ 3575.564343] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:9858:4c7cba27
[ 3575.610167] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-73.ucode failed with error -2
[ 3575.610195] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-72.ucode failed with error -2
[ 3575.610697] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[ 3575.610719] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 0.0.2.36
[ 3575.611123] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 71.058653f6.0 ty-a0-gf-a0-71.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[ 3575.656549] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX210 160MHz, REV=0x420
[ 3575.663397] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: reporting RF_KILL (radio disabled)
[ 3575.811807] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded PNVM version 05a8dfca
[ 3575.823466] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected RF GF, rfid=0x10d000
[ 3575.894946] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: base HW address: 8c:f8:c5:3b:dc:c4
[ 3575.949398] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0 wlp1s0: renamed from wlan0
```

The driver seems to be ready, but it still need to get the firmware for the chip, that doesn't work:

```
root@laptop-02# sudo dkms install backport-iwlwifi/8400

Kernel preparation unnecessary for this kernel. Skipping...

Building module:
cleaning build area...
'make' -j4 KLIB=/lib/modules/5.15.0-46-generic...(bad exit status: 2)
ERROR (dkms apport): binary package for backport-iwlwifi: 8400 not found
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 5.15.0-46-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/backport-iwlwifi/8400/build/make.log for more information.
```

I downloaded drivers from here:
https://www.intel.de/content/www/de/de/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

I mainly followed this post in the procedure (answer 3):
[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS driver Intel Wi-Fi 6E AX210 160MHz](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1326386/ubuntu-20-04-lts-driver-intel-wi-fi-6e-ax210-160mhz)

Many thanks to everybody for any support. Please keep in mind, I'm still a beginner with Linux ;)

Comment: The manual says: "To enable wireless Networking, press Fn + PrtScr." Does that change the result of: `rfkill list all`? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

I just wanted to let you know that the problem resolved itself. Seems like Ubuntu has updated itself here. Because I just shut down the laptop overnight. When I started it again the next day, WLAN (including WPA3 encryption) worked without any problems.

So unfortunately I can't post a solution.