# Ubuntu doesn't recognize wifi on Asus ROG STRIX Z590-E motherboard

Tags: drivers, wireless, asus

I've been trying to troubleshoot this for a while to no avail. The best advice I saw said that it might be a drive issue and Ubuntu would detect which one to download in the "Additional Drives" in "Software & Updates". However, when I open that I don't see anything about my wifi card, it just shows info about my GPU.

[image]

When I run `lscpi -v` it does look like the system detects the wifi adapter on the MOBO:

```
07:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Device 2725 (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device 0024
    Flags: fast devsel, IRQ 19
    Memory at a2900000 (64-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=16K]
    Capabilities: [c8] Power Management version 3
    Capabilities: [d0] MSI: Enable- Count=1/1 Maskable- 64bit+
    Capabilities: [40] Express Endpoint, MSI 00
    Capabilities: [80] MSI-X: Enable- Count=16 Masked-
    Capabilities: [100] Advanced Error Reporting
    Capabilities: [14c] Latency Tolerance Reporting
    Capabilities: [154] L1 PM Substates
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
```

But I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm wondering if maybe the kernel just doesn't support this device yet (the mobo only came out 2 months ago in 2021-feb, so maybe a linux driver just doesn't exist yet? I checked the [ASUS website](https://rog.asus.com/motherboards/rog-strix/rog-strix-z590-e-gaming-wifi-model/helpdesk_download), and they have window drivers but nothing for linux ).

EDIT 1:

I just found some more debugging info with `dmesg | grep iwlwifi`:

```
[    7.982178] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    7.987140] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987257] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987367] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987489] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987504] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987520] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987534] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987631] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987646] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987658] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987671] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-46.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987683] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-45.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987698] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-44.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987709] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-43.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987723] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-42.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987733] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-41.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987743] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-40.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987756] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-39.ucode failed with error -2
[    7.987757] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: no suitable firmware found!
[    7.987760] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: minimum version required: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-39
[    7.987761] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: maximum version supported: iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-56
[    7.987762] iwlwifi 0000:07:00.0: check git://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git
```

On the ROG website I found that the MOBO I have has "Wi-Fi 6", and from this message it may look like the kernel doesn't have support for that yet? I sent to this site: https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git but I have no idea what to do with this.

Comment: Which Ubuntu are you working with?  Because I have an AX200 card from Intel in my laptop here and it's a Wifi 6 card and works fine in 20.04.  You don't state which Ubuntu version you're working with, and it's possible the version of Ubuntu you're trying to use doesn't have a new enough `iwlwifi` driver in it.  Which may simply mean you need to use a newer Ubuntu version.

Comment: Potentially related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1301607/wifi-intel-ax210ngw-is-not-recognized

Comment: See also comments below the answer about *ukuu*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This adapter you've mentioned is, I believe, the AX210 wifi card from Intel - Intel AX210NGW - requires newer version support than the AX200 card (which I have) needs.  And that newer support requires a linux kernel version of 5.10 or higher, according to the [iwlwifi drivers list of supported cards](https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi).

Unfortunately, the only Ubuntu version that has support for this card based on the version of the Kernel on the operating system is 21.04 - Hirsute Hippo.  This means you need to install the latest version of Ubuntu that was released last week.  This is the only way to get a version of Ubuntu that will work with the card.

Comment: This explains everything perfectly. Are there any ppas or projects that backport to 20.04? If not, upgrading to 21.04 isn't a big deal.

Comment: @Erotemic No, there are no PPAs or projects that backport the kernel to 20.04 at this time which are officially supported.  This eventually happens and is available with the HWE stacks at LTS point releases, however the next point release will not happen until at least July, and does not carry any guarantee it'll have the driver versions required.  So if you need the support *now* you need to upgrade to 21.04.  Otherwise, wait until the 20.04.3 point release and use the HWE kernels in that point release.

Comment: @ThomasWard Ukuu does install nicely any kernel on Ubuntu (It's now a [pay-once app](https://teejeetech.com/product/ukuu/)),  I've been using it on my laptops satisfyingly.

Comment: @Déjàvu doing so is likely to make you skip security releases, etc. and though it can install the newer kernels it doesn't necessarily mean it's going to include the iwlwifi stuff properly for Ubuntu to work.  It's why I did not mention ukuu.

Comment: @ThomasWard *ukuu* needs to be run from time to time to get the latest updates, that's right. I cannot *guarantee* wifi will work after a kernel upgrade, but based on my own experience, it did fix wifi and graphics issues on laptops. Have been using it for years, and to the date, not even one problem.