# Ubuntu 18.04.5 / 20.04 not internet connection (both LAN and WiFi)

Tags: networking, 18.04, wireless, 20.04, internet

I downloaded the Ubuntu 18.04.5 distribution from the official website and installed it on my new Lenovo ThinkPad T15 Gen2 laptop. After installation, it turned out that the settings for LAN are missing in the Network interface

https://ibb.co/MVC3DFJ

And the Wifi settings indicated that No Wi-Fi adapter Found

```
lspci | grep -i net
```

https://ibb.co/7Cw4zWz

```
sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

https://ibb.co/GCVYvNN

ps. try to install 20.04  same result

Comment: Please show us: `sudo modprobe iwlwifi && sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 updated answer

Comment: Please see: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1335033/ubuntu-doesnt-recognize-wifi-on-asus-rog-strix-z590-e-motherboard I recommend that you install 21.04 and check again: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: @chili555 You may wish to point OP to https://askubuntu.com/questions/1356118/ax210-wifi-not-working-on-ubuntu21-04/1356136#1356136 or https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352653/intel-ax201-wi-fi-6-is-not-working-on-ubuntu-21-04/1353300#1353300. OP has a firmware problem too.

Comment: @heynnema I'm not quite sure it's the same problem. We don't see any "No config found..." here. Let's see what 21.04 brings us.

Comment: @chili555 I think OP's machine has an Intel AX210. Also isn't finding the right firmware. I think that for a short time, some earlier versions of Ubuntu DID find the AX210.

Comment: @heynnema  Correct. In my 21.04 machine, -59-ucode is called for in `modinfo iwlwifi` and -59.ucode is present in /usr/lib/firmware. So, fingers crossed. Sorry, OP, we often have these little side discussions!

Comment: @chili555 OP's iwlwifi is looking for -39 to -50. Suspect they need `linux-firmware` or Intel firmware files.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/128716/discussion-between-chili555-and-heynnema).

Comment: Thank you guys for the advice. I will try to install 20.1 and write the results

Comment: Guys, good news. Installing version 21.04 seems to have solved all the problems.
Thank you so much!
Am I correct in assuming that all future versions of the system will have the drivers I need and I don't have to worry about upgrading?

Comment: @chili555 Note the OP's last comment.

Comment: I shall propose an answer that I hope you will accept: https://askubuntu.com/tour This will be useful to searchers with the same problem. Thanks.

Comment: All future versions should work perfectly. I'm very glad it's working!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Ubuntu 18.04 and also 20.04, you get the same symptom:

> Direct firmware load xx.ucode failed with error -2

In fact, the referenced firmware files are unavailable anywhere.

This AX210 device is not, according to Intel, supported until kernel versions 5.10 and later: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi

> Wi-Fi 6E products Intel® Wi-Fi 6E AX210 (5.10)

Ubuntu 21.04 shipped with kernel version 5.11, suggesting full support for your device. My own 21.04 install suggests that the driver iwlwifi supports your device:

```
chili@T440p:~$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep 2725
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002725sv*sd000000B0bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00008086d00002725sv*sd00006024bc*sc*i*
<snip>
chili@T440p:~$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep ty-a0-gf-a0
firmware:       iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode
chili@T440p:~$ ls /usr/lib/firmware | grep ty-a0-gf-a0
iwlwifi-ty-a0-gf-a0-59.ucode
```

Therefore, I suggested that you install Ubuntu 21.04 and, after you did, your wireless is working as expected.