# MSI laptop WiFi fails in Ubuntu 18 LTS AOK in Windows 10

Tags: networking, dual-boot, system-installation

I've added dual boot with Ubuntu 18.04 LTS to the original Windows 10 , and all runs good.

But, in Ubuntu my laptop (an [MSI Prestige 15](https://us.msi.com/Content-Creation/Prestige-15-A10X)) doesn't detect the WiFi adapter, so i cant connect to the internet. I've tried to use a USB stick to update everything but it didn't work to the WiFi adapter.

What can i do?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: new here, sorry, should have been a comment.

It works in newer kernels(I have it on a Prestige 15 with ubuntu 19.10 and Manjaro). I believe there is a backport of iwlwifi for the intel ax200 do a quick search. The same wifi chip is also in the Lenovo X1 Extreme gen 2 and P1 gen 2, razer 15, XPS 15 7590.

Here is a discussion. I didn't have to follow these steps because I had a 19.04 install which I moved over, and just updated to 19.10 to get the newer kernel.

[Intel wifi Support for AX200 (Cyclone Peak)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149116/intel-wifi-support-for-ax200-cyclone-peak/1161596#1161596)

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar problem with my mainboard [MSI Meg x570 Unify](https://www.msi.com/Motherboard/MEG-X570-UNIFY)
which has a built-in intel wifi. This line I found [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199665/intel-wifi-ax200-msi-x570-ace)
helped me.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-oem-osp1
```

Luckily, I have an old external USB wifi that I used to run the above command then restarted. After that, the built-in wifi worked. Notice that, in my case, it was a kernel problem. I have installed Ubuntu 20.04 before and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, a dualboot system with Windows 10 and Kubuntu.

After google it, I tried the drivers update for my Intel Wifi6 AX200 card but it didn't work. In parallel I had problems with a second hard disk shared by Windows and Linux, which was mounted in read-only file system mode. So, I realized that Windows was blocking the disk because of the Fast-Startup. I disabled it and now the disk has read-write permissions and the wifi is working... I know it does not make sense...