# Intel WiFi AX200 - MSI x570 ACE

Tags: networking, drivers, intel

Trying to get Ubuntu up and running on my MSI x570 ACE.

Everything seems to be working fine except WiFi (Intel ax200) and Realtek network drivers. I tried downloading the latest firmware from Intel's [website](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html) and copying it to `/lib/firmware/`. Rebooted, no result.

```
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.10
Release:    19.10
Codename:   eoan
```

---

```
  ~$ lshw -C network 
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
       logical name: enp38s0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:d8:61:75:d9:1e
       size: 1Gbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 32 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k duplex=full firmware=0. 6-1 ip=192.168.1.144 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=twisted pair speed=1Gbit/s
       resources: irq:24 memory:f7800000-f781ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:f7820000-f7823fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Ethernet controller
       product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:27:00.0
       version: 00
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7700000-f770ffff memory:f7710000-f7713fff memory:f7720000-f778ffff memory:f7790000-f77abfff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Intel Corporation
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:28:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:f7600000-f7603fff
WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Added output as requested:

```
5.3.0-24-generic #26-Ubuntu SMP Thu Nov 14 01:33:18 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
[    6.183238] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    6.505795] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:28:00.0 failed with error -110
```

---

```
 lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
26:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
    Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1462:7c35]
    Kernel driver in use: igb
    Kernel modules: igb
27:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8125]
--
28:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    DeviceName: RTL8111EPV
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084]
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

After reinstall:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwl

    [    3.439381] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
    [    3.456558] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
    [    3.456561] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
    [    3.456562] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
    [    3.456768] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
    [    3.479627] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
    [    3.490548] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
    [    3.490903] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
    [    3.639001] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: base HW address: 38:00:25:aa:90:33
    [    3.685024] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0 wlo1: renamed from wlan0
    [   10.030351] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
    [   10.177348] iwlwifi 0000:28:00.0: FW already configured (0) - re-configuring
```

---

```
$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
        26:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation I211 Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1539] (rev 03)
            Subsystem: Micro-Star International Co., Ltd. [MSI] I211 Gigabit Network Connection [1462:7c35]
            Kernel driver in use: igb
            Kernel modules: igb
        27:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. Device [10ec:8125]
        --
        28:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
            DeviceName: RTL8111EPV
            Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084]
            Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
        0: hci0: Bluetooth
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
        1: phy0: Wireless LAN
            Soft blocked: no
            Hard blocked: no
```

---

```
$ lshw -C network 
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: I211 Gigabit Network Connection
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:26:00.0
           logical name: enp38s0
           version: 03
           serial: 00:d8:61:75:d9:1e
           capacity: 1Gbit/s
           width: 32 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
           configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=igb driverversion=5.6.0-k firmware=0. 6-1 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
           resources: irq:24 memory:f7800000-f781ffff ioport:e000(size=32) memory:f7820000-f7823fff
      *-network UNCLAIMED
           description: Ethernet controller
           product: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:27:00.0
           version: 00
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: bus_master cap_list
           configuration: latency=0
           resources: ioport:d000(size=256) memory:f7700000-f770ffff memory:f7710000-f7713fff memory:f7720000-f778ffff memory:f7790000-f77abfff
      *-network
           description: Wireless interface
           product: Intel Corporation
           vendor: Intel Corporation
           physical id: 0
           bus info: pci@0000:28:00.0
           logical name: wlo1
           version: 1a
           serial: 38:00:25:aa:90:33
           width: 64 bits
           clock: 33MHz
           capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
           configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.3.0-24-generic firmware=48.4fa0041f.0 ip=192.168.1.139 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11
           resources: irq:42 memory:f7600000-f7603fff
    WARNING: output may be incomplete or inaccurate, you should run this program as super-user.
```

Was able to get them all working, the realtek driver was installed from here: [Link](https://www.realtek.com/en/component/zoo/category/network-interface-controllers-10-100-1000m-gigabit-ethernet-usb-3-0-software)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `uname -a; dmesg | grep iwl` terminal command.

Comment: And also `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list`

Comment: Added the outputs, seems like the adapters don't want to let them enable, strange. Works like  charm in windows - system is not dual booted, only Ubuntu on this drive. BIOS is set to use UEFI

Comment: This device is supported by this kernel. But the probe failed. It looks like a hardware problem.

Comment: I'll try and disable UEFI mode in BIOS and see if there is some settings in the bios. The hardware is flawless, works like a charm in Windows :)

Answer (score 2):

With a working internet connection by ethernet, tethered or any means possible, open a terminal and do:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install linux-oem-osp1
```

Reboot and show us:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

Comment: Hi, I will try this tomorrow. Is this for installing the OEM firmware? If so I already kinda tried it, but will give it another go to collect the log. This network adapter is strange, when I install windows 10, the adapter doesn't show up untill the specific windows driver has been isntalled. I was using the Intel gigabit port with PoE, the realtek adapter doesn't either have drivers in the kernel it seems like, but I dont care about it. Only care about wifi :D

Comment: This solved my issue with msi meg x570 ace wifi not working with ubuntu 18.04 on a fresh install.

Comment: I'm having the exact same issue, but this didn't help.

Comment: @AdrianElder Please start your own new question. I'll be glad to help.

Comment: @chili555 thank you! I'll post it here in case someone is having a similar issue and mine helps resolve it. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1199665/intel-wifi-ax200-msi-x570-ace