# WiFi Adapter AX201 Not Found: Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: drivers, 18.04, iwlwifi, ubuntu-drivers

Please note that this question is specific to Intel WiFi adapters.

My laptop is an HP ENVY with an Intel AX201 Wifi Adapter. I've dualbooted Ubuntu with Windows.

**AX201** WiFi adapter is not supported by latest Ubuntu 18.04 version, because Ubuntu 18.04 comes with Linux Kernel 5.0, whereas support for AX201 comes built-in in Linux Kernel 5.2+. Canonical claims that Ubuntu 18.04 will get Linux Kernel 5.3 sometime next year. However, I wont be able to wait that long.

I tried downloading and installing Kernel 5.2.14, but I cant go beyond Grub: I get the error:

> error: you need to load the kernel first.

Other option is to download the Intel Backport Driver, which I tried. That didn't seem to work either. As per the tutorials, I've restarted frequently, but that didnt work either.

Also I'm not quite sure if Intel IWLWIFI Backport driver supports AX201 in the first place.

WiFi works while I'm booted in Windows.

What should I do? 
Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**

I tried out @Pilot6's answer, and it worked. Thanks!

I have one last question: I've read that if you upgrade the Kernel beyond what Ubuntu 18.4 supports, its kinda unsafe (which I read as prone to system crashes).

I dont want system crashes because I have only one partition (root) for Ubuntu, and any crash would likely mean all my data is lost. One method forward would be to split my Ubuntu partition into root and home.

So if I want to access WiFi on my device safely without risking any crashes, what should I do?

My understanding of Ubuntu and Linux may be wrong as they are built on forum answers only. Please correct me if Im wrong anywhere.

Comment: It is unclear how you tried to install a kernel. It looks like you couldn't do it.

Comment: I upgraded using the .deb packages. I followed this example ot get 
 Kernel v5.2.14: http://www.theubuntumaniac.com/2019/09/update-kernel-5214-on-ubuntu-linux-mint.html

Comment: That doesn't look correct to me anyway.

Comment: If you installed kernel form the official repos, it is quite safe to use. The 5.3 kernel will get updates and will be official HWE soon. Please accept my answer if it works.

Comment: I had the same problem on Lenovo Yoga C740, and this here fixed the problem --> https://askubuntu.com/questions/1156167/unable-to-get-wifi-adapter-working-clean-19-04-install-network-unclaimed/1156246#1156246. There is no need to upgrade to newer kernel, just install the driver ...

Comment: @kannzzmm2 I tried that, but I couldn't figure out how to install the driver. Tried restarting multiple times. Tried installing the firmware along with the driver too.

It could be because I installed Ubuntu with Secure Boot enabled, I've read this answer at some places. But as of now Pilot6's answer is working well, so I'll let you know. Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This wireless adapter is supported by the 5.3 Linux kernel.

You can install the 5.3 kernel already a normal "Ubuntu" way.

Run in a terminal

```
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge
```

That will install the 5.3 kernel used in Ubuntu 19.10.

As soon as the 5.3 kernel is provided by `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` (without edge), you can replace the meta package.

Some time next year `linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge` will pull some next kernel and `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` will pull the `5.3`. If you don't want to switch to a new major kernel version, you can always remove `linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge` and install `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` later.

Comment: You'd have to explain to me: what meta package?

Comment: `linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge` is a meta package. Now it pulls the 5.3 kernel. After it is finally added to `bionic`, you can remove it and install `linux-generic-hwe-18.04`. It is not relevant now. If you have questions about it, you can always ask next year. I gave a working solution for now.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Work well on Razer Studio 15"

Comment: There is no need for the `edge` now. The 5.3 kernel is pooled by `linux-generic-hwe-18.04` now. The meta package can be removed.

Comment: @Pilot6 What if I'm on Ubuntu 16.04.6, which ships with [HWE](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/LTSEnablementStack) by default. What would you suggest me to do?

Comment: I suggest to ask another question, because you have a different problem.

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem on Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Dell Precision 7550). Open a terminal and follow these steps:

```
sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
sudo apt-get update
sudo modprobe iwlwifi
```

Then running the following command:

```
lshw -C Network
```

If you saw `driver=iwlwifi` then the wifi should be installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I used a newer kernel to fix this problem,
Usage of the mainline kernal 6.1+ edition worked for me.
https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/mainline