# Why does ubuntu not show wireless interfaces?

Tags: networking, drivers, intel, iwlwifi

I've a device:

```
admin@sintrones-abox:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic

admin@sintrones-abox:~$ uname -r
5.4.0-122-generic
```

On this device is assembled a `Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX201`. To be sure that it is assembled correctly, I removed and reassembled it several times. Actually, when I run the command `lshw -c network`, I can see no wireless adapter or interface. It is like the card is inexistent. Why is this happening? I paste some log of my system obtained with a script:

```
https://pastebin.ubuntu.com/p/bX6mfsZ5z9/
```

In `/usr/src/` I have `backport-iwlwifi-8324`
and in `/lib/firmware` I have:

```
admin@sintrones-abox:~$ ls /lib/firmware/
1a98-INTEL-EDK2-2-tplg.bin   i6050-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf          README
3com                         i915                           README.iwlwifi-Qu.ucode
a300_pfp.fw                  imx                            regulatory.db
a300_pm4.fw                  intel                          regulatory.db.p7s
acenic                       intel-ucode                    rockchip
adaptec                      ipw2100-1.3.fw                 rp2.fw
advansys                     ipw2100-1.3-i.fw               rsi
agere_ap_fw.bin              ipw2100-1.3-p.fw               rsi_91x.fw
agere_sta_fw.bin             ipw2200-bss.fw                 rt2561.bin
amdgpu                       ipw2200-ibss.fw                rt2561s.bin
amd-ucode                    ipw2200-sniffer.fw             rt2661.bin
ar3k                         isci                           rt2860.bin
ar5523.bin                   kaweth                         rt2870.bin
as102_data1_st.hex           keyspan                        rt3070.bin
as102_data2_st.hex           keyspan_pda                    rt3090.bin
asihpi                       korg                           rt3290.bin
ath10k                       lbtf_usb.bin                   rt73.bin
ath3k-1.fw                   lgs8g75.fw                     RTL8192E
ath6k                        libertas                       rtl_bt
ath9k_htc                    LICENSE.iwlwifi-Qu.ucode       rtl_nic
atmel                        liquidio                       rtlwifi
atmel_at76c504_2958.bin      matrox                         rtw88
atmel_at76c504a_2958.bin     mediatek                       s2250.fw
atmsar11.fw                  mellanox                       s2250_loader.fw
atusb                        moxa                           s5p-mfc.fw
av7110                       mrvl                           s5p-mfc-v6.fw
bnx2                         mt7601u.bin                    s5p-mfc-v6-v2.fw
bnx2x                        mt7650.bin                     s5p-mfc-v7.fw
brcm                         mt7662.bin                     s5p-mfc-v8.fw
carl9170-1.fw                mt7662_rom_patch.bin           sb16
carl9170fw                   mts_cdma.fw                    sdd_sagrad_1091_1098.bin
cavium                       mts_edge.fw                    slicoss
cbfw-3.2.1.1.bin             mts_gsm.fw                     sun
cbfw-3.2.3.0.bin             mts_mt9234mu.fw                tehuti
cbfw-3.2.5.1.bin             mts_mt9234zba.fw               ti_3410.fw
cis                          mwl8k                          ti_5052.fw
configure                    mwlwifi                        ti-connectivity
cpia2                        myri10ge_eth_big_z8e.dat       tigon
ct2fw-3.2.1.1.bin            myri10ge_ethp_big_z8e.dat      ti-keystone
ct2fw-3.2.3.0.bin            myri10ge_ethp_z8e.dat          tlg2300_firmware.bin
ct2fw-3.2.5.1.bin            myri10ge_eth_z8e.dat           ttusb-budget
ctefx.bin                    myri10ge_rss_eth_big_z8e.dat   ueagle-atm
ctfw-3.2.1.1.bin             myri10ge_rss_ethp_big_z8e.dat  usbdux
ctfw-3.2.3.0.bin             myri10ge_rss_ethp_z8e.dat      usbduxfast_firmware.bin
ctfw-3.2.5.1.bin             myri10ge_rss_eth_z8e.dat       usbdux_firmware.bin
ctspeq.bin                   netronome                      usbduxsigma_firmware.bin
cxgb3                        NPE-B                          v4l-cx231xx-avcore-01.fw
cxgb4                        NPE-C                          v4l-cx23418-apu.fw
dsp56k                       nvidia                         v4l-cx23418-cpu.fw
dvb-fe-xc4000-1.4.1.fw       ositech                        v4l-cx23418-dig.fw
dvb-fe-xc5000-1.6.114.fw     phanfw.bin                     v4l-cx2341x-dec.fw
dvb-fe-xc5000c-4.1.30.7.fw   qat_895xcc.bin                 v4l-cx2341x-enc.fw
dvb-usb-dib0700-1.20.fw      qat_895xcc_mmp.bin             v4l-cx2341x-init.mpg
dvb-usb-it9135-01.fw         qat_c3xxx.bin                  v4l-cx23885-avcore-01.fw
dvb-usb-it9135-02.fw         qat_c3xxx_mmp.bin              v4l-cx25840.fw
dvb-usb-terratec-h5-drxk.fw  qat_c62x.bin                   v4l-pvrusb2-24xxx-01.fw
e100                         qat_c62x_mmp.bin               v4l-pvrusb2-29xxx-01.fw
ea                           qat_mmp.bin                    vicam
edgeport                     qca                            vntwusb.fw
emi26                        qcom                           vpu_d.bin
emi62                        qed                            vpu_p.bin
ene-ub6250                   ql2100_fw.bin                  vxge
ess                          ql2200_fw.bin                  WHENCE.ubuntu
f2255usb.bin                 ql2300_fw.bin                  whiteheat.fw
go7007                       ql2322_fw.bin                  whiteheat_loader.fw
hfi1_dc8051.fw               ql2400_fw.bin                  wil6210.brd
hfi1_fabric.fw               ql2500_fw.bin                  wil6210.fw
hfi1_pcie.fw                 qlogic                         wsm_22.bin
hfi1_sbus.fw                 r128                           yam
htc_7010.fw                  r8a779x_usb3_v1.dlmem          yamaha
htc_9271.fw                  r8a779x_usb3_v2.dlmem          zd1201-ap.fw
i2400m-fw-usb-1.4.sbcf       r8a779x_usb3_v3.dlmem          zd1201.fw
i2400m-fw-usb-1.5.sbcf       radeon                         zd1211


admin@sintrones-abox:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Device 9b43 (rev 05)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Device 9bc5 (rev 05)
00:12.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 06f9
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation Device 06ed
00:14.2 RAM memory: Intel Corporation Device 06ef
00:14.5 SD Host controller: Intel Corporation Device 06f5
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation Device 06e0
00:16.3 Serial controller: Intel Corporation Device 06e3
00:17.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation Device 06d2
00:1b.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06ac (rev f0)
00:1b.5 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06ad (rev f0)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06bd (rev f0)
00:1c.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06be (rev f0)
00:1c.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06bf (rev f0)
00:1d.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b0 (rev f0)
00:1d.1 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b1 (rev f0)
00:1d.6 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b6 (rev f0)
00:1d.7 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation Device 06b7 (rev f0)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation Device 0687
00:1f.3 Audio device: Intel Corporation Device 06c8
00:1f.4 SMBus: Intel Corporation Device 06a3
00:1f.5 Serial bus controller [0c80]: Intel Corporation Device 06a4
00:1f.6 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation Device 0d4c
01:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
02:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
03:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
04:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
05:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
06:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
07:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
09:00.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation I210 Gigabit Network Connection (rev 03)
```

What's happening? Thank you everybody
P.S. All the others question on this site, unfortunately, can't solve my problem

Comment: Is it a PCI device? Add output of `lspci` then.

Comment: added to the question

Comment: Either you MB doesn't support the device, or the device is broken.

Comment: It is not about drivers. Unless you see the device in `lspci` thinking about drivers is useless.

Comment: sudo lshw -C network && sudo modinfo iwlwifi  About the module: https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi  Maybe it will help: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196370/intel-wi-fi-6-ax201-module-causing-wi-fi-not-detected-errors-upon-fresh-install  apt-cache show linux-image-generic-hwe-18.04-edge && sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04-edge

Comment: Does this answer your question? [My wireless/WiFi connection does not work. What information is needed to diagnose the issue?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/425155/my-wireless-wifi-connection-does-not-work-what-information-is-needed-to-diagnos)