# Where to get the drivers that are used in the developer edition of the Dell XPS 13 7390 (Fall 2019)?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, dell

I'm trying to install a dual boot Windows 10/Ubuntu 18.04 on my XPS 7390 Developer Edition. Initially Ubuntu 18.04 was installed by Dell. Wifi worked flawlessly on this version.

Today I installed Windows and then a dual boot with the standard Ubuntu 18.04 distribution. This worked, but the Wifi-Card was not being identified in this Ubuntu version.

Now I used the Dell Recovery ISO to get back to the inital state. Wifi is working again. But I still want the dual boot. Is there any way to get the drivers that Dell put in their custom Ubuntu? While they offer windows drivers for the Killer Wifi Card on their website I can't seem to find any ubuntu drivers.

**As requested by @Pilot6:**

```
~$ lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Bigfoot Networks, Inc. Device [1a56:1653]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
    Kernel modules: iwlwifi
03:00.0 PCI bridge [0604]: Intel Corporation JHL6540 Thunderbolt 3 Bridge (C step) [Alpine Ridge 4C 2016] [8086:15d3] (rev 02)
0: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: The correct question would be "How to install wireless drivers on this laptop". You don't need to find specifically that Dell drivers. Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Yes you're right. Having the right drivers for the wifi card would be enough. But as they are not as easily accessible as the windows drivers from Dell and I'm not very familiar with linux finding these drivers is not so easy for me. I added the requested information.

Comment: This is a bit different device, but the solution is the same.

Comment: The correct link is https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196308/wifi-adapter-ax201-not-found-ubuntu-18-04

Comment: @Pilot6 Thank you! For Clarification: You think that my WiFi card is supported by the new 5.3 Kernel? So I just install Ubuntu 18.04 in dual boot and update the kernel?

Comment: Also should I expect that other functionalities that work on the custom Dell version of Ubuntu 18.04 won't work on my clean installation of 18.04?

Comment: You need to install the 5.3 kernel as indicated in the answer but you don't need to reinstall ubuntu.

Comment: I have no idea what are " other functionalities that work on the custom Dell version", but I am sure it's not a rocket science as well.

Comment: Well I executed the comment in the Dell version of Ubuntu where the WiFi is working fine. I want to make a dual boot now. This requires me reinstalling Ubuntu.

Comment: Okay. I will try this then. And with other functionalities I was referring to bluetooth etc.

Comment: Is there a way to install the new kernel without internet via usb? My laptop does not have LAN what makes it hard to connect it to the internet without the driver. @Pilot6

Comment: @Eliah Kagan, I think it does. But I can't run the installation

Comment: You can connect your phone and use it as a USB modem.

Comment: This is a great idea. I can access the web this way. But when entering the command to install the new kernel it says that some archives couldn't be fetched. eventhough there is internet connection @Pilot6

Comment: Run `sudo apt update` first.