# wi-fi adapter not found on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: boot, networking, dual-boot, iwlwifi

I know this (kinda) a repost, but all the other threads on here haven't helped me so far.

I put a drive with an existing dual-boot setup of Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10 in a new laptop. The Wi-fi is working fine on Windows but on didn't work on Ubuntu. I tried a bunch of solutions none of which went anywhere. So I decided to erase the Ubuntu partition and reinstalled it. The adapter still doesn't show up.

While typing this I found this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196308/wifi-adapter-ax201-not-found-ubuntu-18-04) which is exactly my problem. But after the using the answer, the laptop either gets stuck while booting or after booting normally and letting me use ubuntu, blacks out the screen after ~1min.

I hope someone is able to help me.

My laptop is an Omen 15-dh0201ng.
I appended the output of the terminal command that I found on here, but I forgot what the exact command was.

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/G73xRfvtH9/

Answer (score 0):

The solution is quite simple.

Temproarily connect to internet and run in a terminal:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install linux-generic-hwe-18.04
```

Reboot.

That will install the 5.3 kernel. It supports this wireless adapter.

Comment: This just results in a broken start up of ubuntu.
https://imgur.com/a/z2wPizy

Comment: This is some diffrent problem the 5.3 kernel should work. Maybe graphics drivers are not comtatible is you istalled any.

Comment: hm, it seems to be that the 5 for the gtx 2060 are not compatible with 5.3

Comment: It should be compatible, but the drivers from Ubuntu repos may be not after the kernel upgrade. They always forget to check it. The driver didn't build, that's the problem. Or you installed it a wrong way.

Comment: Another option is to install `linux-oem-osp1`, which puts you on the 5.0 kernel and has backports to support this WiFi card but doesn't put you on some 5.3 stuff that doesn't seem to be working yet.