# Can I use kernel version 5.2+ on Ubuntu 16.04?

Tags: networking, 16.04, drivers, nvidia, kernel

The question is as the title says: Is it possible to use Kernel version 5.2+ on Ubuntu 16.04? From a quick search, I find multiple ways to do it on Ubuntu 18.04 and forward, but nothing regarding 16.04.

The reason I'm asking this is that I was given a [MSI prestige 14](https://laptopmedia.com/series/msi-prestige-14/) that contains both `Intel® Wi-Fi 6 AX201` adapter and Nvidia GTX1650. The AX201 seems to [only work from kernel version 5.2+](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196308/wifi-adapter-ax201-not-found-ubuntu-18-04), and while I haven't checked yet I suspect GTX1650 also requires some newer nvidia driver versions not available on Ubuntu 16.04. 
(The graphic resolution and zooming is all messed up too atm)

I need Ubuntu 16.04 to run [ROS Kinetic](http://wiki.ros.org/kinetic)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. You can install any kernel on any Ubuntu version. In theory ;) A new kernel gets added to the existing kernels and becomes an option to select in the Grub menu during boot. That does not depend on the version of the operating system installed. What can happen though is that you lose Ubuntu-specific alterations if you pick the mainline kernel.

> I need Ubuntu 16.04 to run ROS Kinetic

No reason to not use 18.04: you are supposed to switch to [ROS Melodic](http://wiki.ros.org/melodic/Installation/Ubuntu) or running it in a [docker container](https://hub.docker.com/_/ros/).

And if you do have software to use that depends on a specific version of an operating system, use VirtualBox for that and do not let your current operating system lag behind. April 2021 is getting closer and closer and then what?

Comment: Not toe mention April 2020 is even closer than April 2024 ;)

Comment: darn it was looking at esm :D

Comment: Hi Rinzwind thank you for the answer! (and sorry for late closure) That's all valid points, and after some further head scratching I've decided to go with a VirtualBox, but I totally forgot the docker option is also possible and might look in to it. Thanks again! :D