# Wifi Issue with Intel AX201

Tags: networking, drivers, network-manager, iwlwifi

Please read the detailed issue as below:

Network Manager:

[image: Settings Dropdown status]

Wifi Settings:

[image: Wifi settings window]

Results of `lshw -class network`:

[image: Screenshot result lshw]

Results of `lspci`:

[image: screenshot result lspci]

Results of `nmcli`:

[image: Screenshot result nmcli]

Wifi is not disabled in the BIOS.

Results of `rfkill`:

[[image: Screenshot result rfkill]][]

Edit: complete dump form `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`:

https://www.codedump.xyz/yml/ZMPz2dNx-WyGzx1G

Comment: You've not mentioned what Ubuntu product, what release of that product.  Are you hoping we guess?  Why not just tell us.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [WiFi Adapter AX201 Not Found: Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1196308/wifi-adapter-ax201-not-found-ubuntu-18-04)

Comment: Please copy and paste terminal results rather than uploading pictures, please edit to include results for `sudo dmesg | grep iwl`

Comment: Hi @guiverc I am using Ubuntu 22.04 LTS

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have added the link to complete dump, pasting here exceeded the limit of characters for the question. At the top I see `Detected Intel(R) Wireless-AC 9560 160MHz, REV=0x351` while `lshw -class network` shows ```*-network:0 DISABLED
 product: Wi-Fi 6 AX201
 vendor: Intel Corporation
 physical id: 14.3
 bus info: pci@0000:00:14.3
 logical name: wlp0s20f3
 version: 20
 width: 64 bits
 clock: 33MHz
 capabilities: bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
 configuration: driver=iwlwifi driverversion=5.19.0-50-generic firmware=72.daa05125.0 QuZ-a0-jf-b0-72.u ```

Comment: See https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?p=2353320#p2353320

Comment: Thank you @Jeremy31 for pointing in the right direction, I tried the 6.1.24LTS kernel, did not work, however when I switched to 6.1-oem it fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue fixed by upgrading to kernel 6.1-oem