# Freeze on wifi authentication -- AX200 chipset, with 18.04, kernel 4.15, and backported iwlwifi

Tags: 18.04, network-manager, iwlwifi, backport

I have a AX200 wifi adapter from Ubit ([link](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07XM6XZ1F)) that I'm trying to use on an 18.04 ubuntu install with kernel 4.15. I can't update the kernel because of needing proper CUDA support, so I've followed the advice [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149116/intel-wifi-support-for-ax200-cyclone-peak) and elsewhere to install the backported iwlwifi driver. I've also installed the iwlwifi-cc-a0-46 firmware [from Intel](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless-networking.html).

Operating system sees the wifi adapter, everything seems hunky-dory until I actually go to connect to my wireless network. I enter my password, click "connect" and then everything freezes. Please help! Here are some diagnostic messages, let me know what else would be helpful:

```
rfkill list all
>>>
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

```
dmesg | grep iwlwifi
>>>
[   11.040689] Loading modules backported from iwlwifi
[   11.040689] iwlwifi-stack-public:master:8613:3ae69204
[   11.097569] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: enabling device (0100 -> 0102)
[   11.104708] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-dbg-cfg.ini failed with error -2
[   11.104848] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-57.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.104857] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-56.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.104863] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.104868] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-54.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.104873] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.105479] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.105492] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.105500] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.105507] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.105515] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.105523] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-47.ucode failed with error -2
[   11.110659] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: loaded firmware version 46.3cfab8da.0 cc-a0-46.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[   11.110675] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[   11.130761] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[   11.291742] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0: base HW address: 4c:1d:96:ba:ba:67
[   11.307461] iwlwifi 0000:02:00.0 wlp2s0: renamed from wlan0
```

```
lspci -nnk | grep -A2 0280
>>>
02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Device [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
    Subsystem: Intel Corporation Device [8086:0084]
    Kernel driver in use: iwlwifi
```

```
modprobe -v backport-iwlwifi
>>>
modprobe: FATAL: Module backport-iwlwifi not found in directory /lib/modules/4.15.0-101-generic
```

```
uname -sr
>>>
Linux 4.15.0-101-generic
```

Any suggestions?

**Update June 11, 2020:**

**I think the issue is probably pointed to by this sequence of statuses from gnome-system-log, but I'm not able to fully parse them myself**:

```
Jun 11 18:02:36 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923756.0240] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'PalaceMesh' (137d3860-14ad-42c0-b931-c7223a817175)
Jun 11 18:02:36 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923756.0244] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="137d3860-14ad-42c0-b931-c7223a817175" name="PalaceMesh" pid=3673 uid=1000 result="success"
Jun 11 18:02:36 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923756.0250] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 11 18:02:36 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923756.0261] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 11 18:02:36 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923756.0270] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'PalaceMesh' has security, but secrets are required.
Jun 11 18:02:36 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923756.0270] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 11 18:02:40 DendriteDesktop org.gnome.Shell.desktop[2816]: Window manager warning: Overwriting existing binding of keysym 73 with keysym 73 (keycode 27).
Jun 11 18:02:51 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <warn>  [1591923771.2563] device (wlp2s0): User canceled the secrets request.
Jun 11 18:02:51 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923771.2564] device (wlp2s0): state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 11 18:02:51 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <warn>  [1591923771.2572] device (wlp2s0): Activation: failed for connection 'PalaceMesh'
Jun 11 18:02:51 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923771.2580] device (wlp2s0): state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 11 18:02:51 DendriteDesktop gnome-shell[1817]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Jun 11 18:02:51 DendriteDesktop kernel: [  643.060538] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlp2s0: link is not ready
Jun 11 18:02:51 DendriteDesktop gnome-shell[2816]: An active wireless connection, in infrastructure mode, involves no access point?
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop gnome-control-c[3673]: g_variant_unref: assertion 'value != NULL' failed
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop dbus-daemon[1066]: [system] Activating via systemd: service name='org.freedesktop.hostname1' unit='dbus-org.freedesktop.hostname1.service' requested by ':1.127' (uid=1000 pid=3673 comm="gnome-control-center " label="unconfined")
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop systemd[1]: Started Run anacron jobs.
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop systemd[1]: Starting Hostname Service...
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop anacron[4337]: Anacron 2.3 started on 2020-06-11
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop anacron[4337]: Normal exit (0 jobs run)
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop gvfsd[2793]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop kernel: [  647.366974] nf_conntrack: default automatic helper assignment has been turned off for security reasons and CT-based  firewall rule not found. Use the iptables CT target to attach helpers instead.
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop gvfsd[2793]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop dbus-daemon[1066]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.hostname1'
Jun 11 18:02:55 DendriteDesktop systemd[1]: Started Hostname Service.
Jun 11 18:02:56 DendriteDesktop gvfsd[2793]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
Jun 11 18:03:15 DendriteDesktop gvfsd[2793]: message repeated 39 times: [ mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied]
Jun 11 18:03:16 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923796.0549] device (wlp2s0): Activation: starting connection 'PalaceMesh' (137d3860-14ad-42c0-b931-c7223a817175)
Jun 11 18:03:16 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923796.0551] audit: op="connection-activate" uuid="137d3860-14ad-42c0-b931-c7223a817175" name="PalaceMesh" pid=3673 uid=1000 result="success"
Jun 11 18:03:16 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923796.0555] device (wlp2s0): state change: disconnected -> prepare (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 11 18:03:16 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923796.0566] device (wlp2s0): state change: prepare -> config (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 11 18:03:16 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923796.0570] device (wlp2s0): Activation: (wifi) access point 'PalaceMesh' has security, but secrets are required.
Jun 11 18:03:16 DendriteDesktop NetworkManager[1117]: <info>  [1591923796.0571] device (wlp2s0): state change: config -> need-auth (reason 'none', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
Jun 11 18:03:16 DendriteDesktop gvfsd[2793]: mkdir failed on directory /var/cache/samba: Permission denied
```

lines above such as

```
state change: need-auth -> failed (reason 'no-secrets', sys-iface-state: 'managed')
```

seem to suggest that Network Manager is unable to authenticate (even though I am providing the correct password) and there seems to be a repeated `mkdir /var/cache/samba` which is failing. I'm not sure why this should be causing my system to COMPLETELY freeze though. The contents of my iwlwifi modprobe config file are:

```
# /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
# iwlwifi will dyamically load either iwldvm or iwlmvm depending on the
# microcode file installed on the system.  When removing iwlwifi, first
# remove the iwl?vm module and then iwlwifi.
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211
```

Please, does anyone have a clue what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

The ax200 drivers requires a 5.1+ kernel
[here](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/support/articles/000005511/network-and-i-o/wireless.html).
I did an install of Ubuntu 20.10 (kernel 5.8) with a card based on ax200 chipset
that apparently ships with a rather recent firmware iwlwifi-cc-a0-55.ucode, I've been able to get it to work in station (managed) mode and ap mode (but only on 2.4ghz)

there have been various threads discussing some different issues related to ax200 chipsets. one of them mentioned using a PCIe x 1 slot
[here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269313/ax200-wifi-and-20-04).

then in other forums there are bummers with earlier versions of the ucode firmware
[link](https://forum.openwrt.org/t/intel-wi-fi-6-ax200/46377).

I'm not sure about the backported kernels and firmware
but if there are other bummers you may want to try using more recent kernels e.g. 5.x along with more recent ucode firmware
[This](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149116/intel-wifi-support-for-ax200-cyclone-peak) link might help.