# AX200 WiFi and 20.04

Tags: networking, wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

I recently purchased an wifi card with an Intel AX200 chipset and I'm unable to get it working.  I upgraded from 18.04 to 20.04 and bumped the kernel to 5.7.1 using ukuu. I've tried with both the kernel driver and backport driver and have had no luck.

I've been using Ubuntu for something like to 10 years, but i'm not an expert by any means on configuring stuff. I suspect this might be a hardware incompatibility, even thought the bluetooth works fine, but I think it's also very likely I'm missing something straightforward since I don't actually know what I'm doing.

Is there anything else I can try to get this card to work?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

dmesg w/ -53 firmware:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    3.215864] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[    3.215884] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 68.3.35.22
[    3.215889] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.215890] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.216257] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 53.c31ac674.0 cc-a0-53.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.216294] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    3.257698] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    4.287191] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5d2d, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    4.287245] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x80482d10
[    4.287278] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x104
[    4.287371] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    4.287403] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[    4.287433] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 53.c31ac674.0 cc-a0-53.ucode
[    4.287470] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[    4.287504] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    4.287528] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    4.287560] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F9A5E | branchlink2
[    4.287597] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E44AC | interruptlink1
[    4.287626] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E44AC | interruptlink2
[    4.287656] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F37FA | data1
[    4.287683] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2
[    4.287710] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | data3
[    4.287738] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    4.287768] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000FA66 | tsf low
[    4.287796] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    4.287822] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    4.287852] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0001585C | time gp2
[    4.287880] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    4.287912] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000035 | uCode version major
[    4.287941] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC31AC674 | uCode version minor
[    4.287972] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[    4.288004] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x18C89000 | board version
[    4.288034] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x8001FF03 | hcmd
[    4.288061] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    4.288085] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    4.288109] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    4.288133] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C0001C | isr3
[    4.288157] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    4.288180] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    4.288208] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F37FA | wait_event
[    4.288233] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    4.288264] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration
[    4.288291] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    4.288319] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    4.288348] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    4.288377] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    4.288406] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000F81C | flow_handler
[    4.288456] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    4.288483] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    4.288515] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x20100222 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    4.288547] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    4.288576] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80467420 | umac branchlink2
[    4.288606] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0086A84 | umac interruptlink1
[    4.288637] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    4.288675] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1
[    4.288704] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
[    4.289742] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[    4.290779] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000035 | umac major
[    4.291832] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC31AC674 | umac minor
[    4.292831] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00015850 | frame pointer
[    4.293798] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886AE4 | stack pointer
[    4.294769] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000FFFF | last host cmd
[    4.295695] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    4.296683] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    4.297613] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x60000100 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    4.297616] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    4.297620] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    4.297623] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    4.297626] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    4.297629] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    4.297632] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    4.297635] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    4.297639] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.297644] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.297649] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    4.297654] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    4.297660] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    4.556133] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

dmesg w/ -48 firmware:

```
$ dmesg | grep iwlwifi
[    3.303893] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-53.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.305800] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-52.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.305827] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-51.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.305847] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-50.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.305866] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwlwifi-cc-a0-49.ucode failed with error -2
[    3.308659] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 43.2.23.17
[    3.308664] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug destination: EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.308665] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Found debug configuration: 0
[    3.308985] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 cc-a0-48.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[    3.309020] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Direct firmware load for iwl-debug-yoyo.bin failed with error -2
[    3.404291] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
[    3.416142] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Applying debug destination EXTERNAL_DRAM
[    3.416759] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Allocated 0x00400000 bytes for firmware monitor.
[    4.447089] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: SecBoot CPU1 Status: 0x5ffc, CPU2 Status: 0x3
[    4.447146] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: UMAC PC: 0x8048c960
[    4.447177] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: LMAC PC: 0x104
[    4.447202] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Collecting data: trigger 15 fired.
[    4.447266] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    4.447297] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 6
[    4.447326] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Loaded firmware version: 48.4fa0041f.0 cc-a0-48.ucode
[    4.447365] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000071 | NMI_INTERRUPT_UMAC_FATAL    
[    4.447402] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x002022F0 | trm_hw_status0
[    4.447436] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | trm_hw_status1
[    4.447470] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F8E3C | branchlink2
[    4.447495] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4FF4 | interruptlink1
[    4.447524] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004E4FF4 | interruptlink2
[    4.447550] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3DB0 | data1
[    4.447575] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00001000 | data2
[    4.447602] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xF0000000 | data3
[    4.447628] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | beacon time
[    4.447660] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000E655 | tsf low
[    4.447684] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | tsf hi
[    4.447712] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | time gp1
[    4.447741] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0001476E | time gp2
[    4.447768] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000001 | uCode revision type
[    4.447801] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000030 | uCode version major
[    4.447831] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4FA0041F | uCode version minor
[    4.447861] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000340 | hw version
[    4.447886] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x18C89000 | board version
[    4.447912] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x8002FF03 | hcmd
[    4.447935] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00020000 | isr0
[    4.447960] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr1
[    4.447989] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x08F00002 | isr2
[    4.448018] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00C0000C | isr3
[    4.448045] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr4
[    4.448071] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | last cmd Id
[    4.448104] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x004F3DB0 | wait_event
[    4.448138] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_control
[    4.448168] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000020 | l2p_duration
[    4.448194] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_mhvalid
[    4.448223] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | l2p_addr_match
[    4.448253] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000009 | lmpm_pmg_sel
[    4.448280] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | timestamp
[    4.448308] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000F81C | flow_handler
[    4.448363] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Start IWL Error Log Dump:
[    4.448394] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Status: 0x00000000, count: 7
[    4.448425] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x20100222 | ADVANCED_SYSASSERT
[    4.448455] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac branchlink1
[    4.448486] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC008CC3C | umac branchlink2
[    4.448515] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0087660 | umac interruptlink1
[    4.448549] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | umac interruptlink2
[    4.448582] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data1
[    4.449667] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data2
[    4.450625] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xDEADBEEF | umac data3
[    4.451706] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000030 | umac major
[    4.452516] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4FA0041F | umac minor
[    4.452518] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00014762 | frame pointer
[    4.454164] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0xC0886B00 | stack pointer
[    4.454814] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000FFFF | last host cmd
[    4.455707] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000000 | isr status reg
[    4.456465] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Fseq Registers:
[    4.457151] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x60005101 | FSEQ_ERROR_CODE
[    4.457903] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80290021 | FSEQ_TOP_INIT_VERSION
[    4.458532] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80050008 | FSEQ_CNVIO_INIT_VERSION
[    4.459167] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000A503 | FSEQ_OTP_VERSION
[    4.459833] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x80000003 | FSEQ_TOP_CONTENT_VERSION
[    4.460457] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x4552414E | FSEQ_ALIVE_TOKEN
[    4.461167] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | FSEQ_CNVI_ID
[    4.461810] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | FSEQ_CNVR_ID
[    4.462476] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00100530 | CNVI_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.463052] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x00000532 | CNVR_AUX_MISC_CHIP
[    4.463716] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x05B0905B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_DIG_DCDC_VTRIM
[    4.463722] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: 0x0000025B | CNVR_SCU_SD_REGS_SD_REG_ACTIVE_VDIG_MIRROR
[    4.463766] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to start RT ucode: -110
[    4.467067] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Firmware not running - cannot dump error
[    4.481891] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: Failed to run INIT ucode: -110
```

```
$ uname -r
5.7.1-050701-generic
```

```
$ modinfo iwlwifi | grep filename
filename:       /lib/modules/5.7.1-050701-generic/kernel/drivers/net/wireless/intel/iwlwifi/iwlwifi.ko
```

```
$ lspci -nnk | grep 0280
01:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Wi-Fi 6 AX200 [8086:2723] (rev 1a)
```

```
$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Network controller
       product: Wi-Fi 6 AX200
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: 1a
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix bus_master cap_list
       configuration: driver=iwlwifi latency=0
       resources: irq:16 memory:f7500000-f7503fff
```

```
$ rfkill list all
0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Comment: "loaded firmware version 53.c31ac674.0 cc-a0-53.ucode" Where did you get the -53 version of the firmware? The latest in linux-firmware for 20.04 is -48. Is it possible that the device won't initiate using an experimental firmware file? Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks! -50, -53, and -55 come from the firmware repository hosted at kernel.org. I think I grabbed them when messing around with the backport drivers.

Updated original post with dmesg content with both 53 and 48 versions of the firmware.

Comment: So far it seems upgrading to a more up-to-date (5.10.17) kernel solved all the problems with AX200 WiFi. But it caused problems with DKMS: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1318213/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I recently bought an Asus AX3000 card (uses AX200 chipset) and upgraded from Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 - had exactly the same problem. Eventually I found this report https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205123 that these cards only work in a PCIe x 1 slot. Initially I put into a a x16 slot on motherboard next to CPU and I had exactly the same symptoms as here. I moved it to a free PCIex1 slot and now works fine.

Good luck!

Comment: That worked! Thanks so much.

Comment: Moving the card from the PCIex16 to x1 slot in a SFF HP 6300 fixed it for me too. Thank you, I lost hours troubleshooting the firmware driver in Ubuntu.