# Razer Blade Pro 17 Wi-fi card not working Ubuntu 20.04.3

Tags: networking, drivers, 20.04, iwlwifi

A fresh install of ubuntu 20.04.3 in a Razor Blade Pro 17 laptop, the wifi card never showed up.

`uname -a` outputs

```
 Linux Razor 5.11.0-41-generic #45~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Wed Nov 10 10:20:10 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

`dmesg | grep iwlwifi` outputs:

```
[    2.333506] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver <br>
[    2.333519] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22 <br>
[    2.333790] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm <br>
[    2.607066] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
```

I also tried [this Intel article](https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html) without success...

After that, I tried Intel support, but they sent me here because it's not a firmware problem but a driver problem, and drivers are provided by Ubuntu...

There it is

```
[    2.498488] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver<br>
[    2.498504] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22<br>
[    2.498780] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm<br>
[    2.678275] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340
```

Same results!

It seems that I've already the last driver or it doesn't want to replace the old ones?!?

I updated to the latest kernel

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.187.23_all.deb
```

The problem persists.

As of 2022-01-18,  the problem still on event if I update to the last kernel wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.187.23_all.deb

Any clue now?

Comment: If your device is not working, then there must be *much more* in dmesg. Please run: `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` and post the entire output here and give us the link: http://paste.ubuntu.com  As for the claim that Ubuntu provides the driver, please check the author: `modinfo iwlwifi | grep -i author` Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: I know that Intel should do more, but, in my opinion, that's the way they get rid of the ball.

Comment: May I please see the link to your paste? Thanks.

Comment: https://www.intel.ca/content/www/ca/en/support/articles/000005511/wireless.html

Comment: I asked for the entirety of `sudo dmesg | grep iwl` to be pasted and received no reply. We can't help you without *much more* information.

Comment: [ 2.333506] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver
[ 2.333519] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: TLV_FW_FSEQ_VERSION: FSEQ Version: 89.3.35.22
[ 2.333790] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm
[ 2.607066] iwlwifi 0000:3e:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Wi-Fi 6 AX200 160MHz, REV=0x340

Comment: Possibly helpful: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1269313/ax200-wifi-and-20-04

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that a valuable clue is:

> api flags index 2 larger than supported by driver

The firmware loads but doesn't activate the device; that is, no wireless interface such as wlp3s0 is created and Network Manager is not prompted to connect.

We see that firmware version -59 is loaded.

> loaded firmware version 59.601f3a66.0 cc-a0-59.ucode op_mode iwlmvm

Newer firmware files are present in the focal-updates, appropriate for Ubuntu 20.04, version of linux-firmware.

Please do:

```
wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/main/l/linux-firmware/linux-firmware_1.187.23_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i linux*.deb
```

Reboot and check the message log:

```
sudo dmesg | grep iwl
```

Is there any improvement?

Comment: No, still not working..

Comment: @DenysLaflamme Please start your own new question.

Comment: DenysLaflamme is the OP. Question has been updated.