# Bluetooth not working with Intel AX200 on Ubuntu despite Wifi working

Tags: networking, bluetooth

My self-built computer won't detect any Bluetooth devices although it can connect with Wifi.

My AX200 uses this [PCIe adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B087RDYYBW). On the adapter, the light signaling Wifi is working is on but the bluetooth light remains off. [Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvphS.jpg)

Here's some terminal output:

```
sudo systemctl status bluetooth

● bluetooth.service - Bluetooth service
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/bluetooth.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
     Active: active (running) since Wed 2022-06-15 07:53:46 PDT; 23min ago
       Docs: man:bluetoothd(8)
   Main PID: 621 (bluetoothd)
     Status: "Running"
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 9269)
     Memory: 2.0M
        CPU: 58ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/bluetooth.service
             └─621 /usr/lib/bluetooth/bluetoothd
```

---

```
rfkill list

0: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no\
```

---

```
sudo dmesg | grep hci0

[    5.602650] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
[    5.602688] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x24800
[    5.602689] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 126-5.22
[    5.602690] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[   58.234933] Bluetooth: hci0: Ignoring error of Inquiry Cancel command
```

I followed the instructions [here](https://linuxways.net/ubuntu/how-to-restart-bluetooth-in-ubuntu-20-04/) for restarting the daemon

I tried using a different Bluetooth manager with the Blueman manager from [here](https://techsphinx.com/linux/install-blueman-ubuntu/)

I tried removing the Wifi card from the adapter then reinserted it, reinserted the PCIe adapter, and re-installing the antennas, but still having the problem.

Here are some [pics](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kT4JB.jpg) of the setup. The USB part of the PCIe adapter is connected to the F_USB2 port if that matters.

Thank you!

Edit:

Here's the output of `sudo dmesg | grep -i blue`

```
[    5.756082] Bluetooth: Core ver 2.22
[    5.756103] NET: Registered PF_BLUETOOTH protocol family
[    5.756104] Bluetooth: HCI device and connection manager initialized
[    5.756107] Bluetooth: HCI socket layer initialized
[    5.756108] Bluetooth: L2CAP socket layer initialized
[    5.756110] Bluetooth: SCO socket layer initialized
[    5.785764] Bluetooth: hci0: Found device firmware: intel/ibt-20-1-3.sfi
[    5.785785] Bluetooth: hci0: Boot Address: 0x24800
[    5.785786] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware Version: 126-5.22
[    5.785787] Bluetooth: hci0: Firmware already loaded
[    6.284501] Bluetooth: BNEP (Ethernet Emulation) ver 1.3
[    6.284503] Bluetooth: BNEP filters: protocol multicast
[    6.284508] Bluetooth: BNEP socket layer initialized
[    6.528262] Bluetooth: RFCOMM TTY layer initialized
[    6.528267] Bluetooth: RFCOMM socket layer initialized
[    6.528270] Bluetooth: RFCOMM ver 1.11
```

Kernel version is `5.15.0-37-generic`

My computer only boots up Ubuntu so no dual-boot with Windows.

Comment: Please add output of `dmesg | grep -i blue`. Is it a dual boot with Windows?

Comment: Also, what kernel are you using? [There was a bug report](https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=205123#c22) about Ubuntu running on kernel 5.16 and the same solution was offered by arch users on Reddit. First, create a new directory. Then, move all the firmware  `/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-cc-a0-xx.ucode` to the new directory except for  `iwlwifi-cc-a0-48.ucode` So, all the other versions of this that are not 48 need to be moved out. To be clear **Move only the files iwlwifi-cc-a0[version.ucode] that you are isolating away from firmware loader in `/lib/firmware/`**.

Comment: Mentioned in the same bug report, it might not work for bluetooth in an x16 slot which is also mentioned [in this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1271055/167115).

Comment: Added info asked in comments in edit above. Also the adapter is connected to an x1 slot

Comment: I've also tried moving all the `iwlwifi-cc-ao-xx.ucode` files except the 48 one but still having problem of not detecting bluetooth devices.

Comment: Have you connected the supplied 9-pin cable?

Comment: By 9-pin cable, do you mean the one connected to the F_USB slot? If so, yes @heynnema

Comment: @Pilot6 Forgot to notify edit

Comment: @mchid Forgot to notify edit

Comment: You should move those files back since it didn't work.