# What do I need to do to get Intel AX200 PCIe to work with Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, iwlwifi

I have recently received a new laptop from my employer.  It came with Windows 10, but I converted it to Ubuntu 20.04.  This is the first time I have had to configure 20.04, and also the first time I have dealt with Intel's AX200 802.11ax PCIe card in Ubuntu.  I have spent hours and hours researching how to get this work.  I have tried many (to the best of my ability) but none of them seem to work.  The card is being recognized by the kernel, but it will not enable it for use.  Some of the key elements I have checked and can provide now are:

```
rh526h@rodneylenny5:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for rh526h: 
[    2.812277] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.226744] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:3a:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Here is the adapter showing in lspci

```
rh526h@rodneylenny5:~$ sudo dmesg | grep iwl
[sudo] password for rh526h: 
Sorry, try again.
[sudo] password for rh526h: 
[    2.812277] iwlwifi 0000:3a:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.226744] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:3a:00.0 failed with error -110
```

Output of lsmod:

```
rh526h@rodneylenny5:~$ lsmod | grep iwl
iwlwifi               364544  0
cfg80211              782336  1 iwlwifi
```

Current kernel image:

```
rh526h@rodneylenny5:~$ uname -r
5.8.0-22-generic
```

I have tried manually updating the drivers by downloading them from Intel, and placing them in the /lib/firmware directory then restarting the laptop
I have also tried installing a backport version of iwlwifi "backport-iwlwifi-dkmn", as this was one of the many solutions that were supposed to fix this issue.

I upgraded the kernel from 5.4 to 5.8 because the later drivers were supposed to only work with an image 5.7 or later.

I am at my wits end and I need help ASAP.  I need this computer for work.  I have a working 18.04 machine that I have to replace with this one.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intel wifi Support for AX200 (Cyclone Peak)](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149116/intel-wifi-support-for-ax200-cyclone-peak)

Comment: you need to go to kernel 5.4.x intel ax200 m.2 key E pcie support is missing from kernels greater than 5.4.x tried 5.18.x and a few lesser numbered kernels.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue with my HP ProBook 650 g5.
I is using the AX200 Intel Wifi-Card too.
After I download all realded firmdriver from GIT
https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware.git/tree/
and did a

```bash
sudo cp *iwl*ucode /lib/firmware/
```

and it works. dmesg | grep wifi shows this line:
[    8.809876] iwlwifi 0000:01:00.0: loaded firmware version 48.4fa0041f.0 op_mode iwlmvm
According to this page:
https://github.com/woodsts/linux-firmware/commit/2ae99744efc14e5329a551251e22b33213224f11
This is this driver:
@@ -1072,6 +1072,27 @@ Version: 48.4fa0041f.0
File: iwlwifi-QuZ-a0-jf-b0-48.ucode
Version: 48.4fa0041f.0

Comment: I can't follow along with this answer.  Since there is no [formatting](https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting), your instructions are ambiguous.  Will you please [edit](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1290559/edit) your answer?  I suggest that you add step-by-step instructions.  Any commands that need to be entered into the terminal should be formatted in a `monospace font` so that we can tell them apart from the surround text.  You can use the GUI formatting tools in the text box where you compose your answer, or you can use Markdown.