# Intel AX200 compilation problem

Tags: iwlwifi

I have compilation problem with backport-iwlwifi

```
make[4]: *** [Makefile:1784: /temp/wifi/backport-iwlwifi] Error 2
make[3]: *** [Makefile.build:13: modules] Error 2
make[2]: *** [Makefile.real:100: modules] Error 2
make[1]: *** [Makefile:43: modules] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:30: default] Error 2
```

maybe I have lack of compilation tools like bison or flex ?
Please tell me what to do to make this compilation happened ?

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release? What are you compiling?

Comment: this is ubuntu 20.04.1

Comment: Then you don't need to compile ancient backports. See their date. What is the real problem? See [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: I'm trying to install backport-iwlwifi-dkms,
I'm reffering to this post:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/1149116/intel-wifi-support-for-ax200-cyclone-peak/1177179#1177179

I'm using kernel 5.9.12 generic version
after command: make -j 4 (I have 4 cores) I'm getting errors and cannot make install

Comment: You don't need any backports on the 5.9 kernel.

Comment: The real problem is that, because on this kernel 5.9.12 I cannot add bluetooth mouse normally - only using blueman works, but after restart I cannot connect mouse again.
I think there is a problem with bluetooth because wifi is working fine.

Comment: ok please advise me what to do with bluetooth,

Comment: These backports are wireless code from new kernels that can be installed to old kernels. It is 100% unrelated to Bluetooth. And it makes no sense trying to install it to the latest kernel.

Comment: Does BT work with Ubuntu kernels?

Comment: ok, regarding BT I have bluez, bluedevil and blueman installed.

Comment: Sp does it work with standard Ubuntu kernels, not mainline?

Comment: regading regular 5.4 kernel it works fine but wifi not working well.

Comment: Problems with the 5.9 are off-topic here. Ubuntu doesn't use this kernel and never will use.

Comment: And as I said the backports won't fix your BT anyway.

Comment: ok, so what mainline should I have with BT working ?

Comment: I suggest trying the 5.8, but not mainline. Install `linux-generic-hwe-20.04-edge` package and select the 5.8 in grub.

Comment: I have installed 5.8 and problem is resolved now.

Comment: Thank You very much, I didn't also realized that mainline is not good.